# Búsqueda SQL entre múltiples tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

tengo las siguientes tablas.

```
TABLA: CLIENTES
id  nombre              cedula      direccion   ciudad          sexo
1   Caroline Covelly    1067411355  Cerca       Barranquilla    Femenino
2   Lucia Torres        1412751261  Lejos       Leon            Femenino
3   Miguel Gamarra      1023502392  Muy Lejos   Sincelejo       Masculino
4   Jesus Gonzalez      1067234656  Medio       Pueblo perdio   Masculino
```

```
TABLA: INVENTARIO
id   nombrep     detallep        precio
1   Chocolatina Chocolate en barra  1000
2   Butifarra   Carne embutida      2000
3   Bollo       Producto casero     4000
4   Gaseosa     Bebida embotellada  30000
5   Pan         Producto casero     500
6   Yuca        Por libra           800
7   Papas       Producto casero     1200
8   Chorizos    Embutido            800
9   Queso       Producto lacteo     7000
10  Suero       Producto lacteo     3000
```

```
id   fecha   producto cantidad cliente
1   2018-10-01  6        2        1
2   2018-10-10  3        4        2
3   2018-10-11  9        3        3
4   2018-10-16  4        7        4
```

Necesito obtener los nombres, cédulas, sexo, nombre de producto, cantidad, precio unitario y precio total que se pagó de todos los productos comprados. Con SQL.

Comment: Que has intentado? por la imagen veo que usas mySql. Por que la etiqueta de sql-server? Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic)

Comment: En preguntas SQL es buena idea incluir una muestra de los datos, pero sugiero hacerlo como texto y no como imagen. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo @FranIslas

Comment: Ya edito @jachguate

Comment: Listo @jachguate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener los datos que deseas, debes *ensamblar* una consulta donde expandas las relaciones que hay entre las tablas haciendo uso de operaciones [`join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21). En el caso concreto de las tablas que muestras y las relaciones que puedo intuir que hay en ellas, yo utilizaría en concreto `inner join`.

Partiendo de la última tabla, que asumo se llama `Ventas` voy a mostrarte cómo relacionarla con la tabla `Inventario`, de manera que tengas una ruta a seguir y ya te queda a ti ensamblar la consulta final que te devuelva todos los resultados.

Para realizar la consulta, voy a asignar un *alias* a cada tabla, de manera que pueda referenciar los campos de cada una sin ambigüedad (un requisito en *SQL*) y sin utilizar todo el nombre de la tabla. Para la tabla `Ventas` usaré el alias `V` y para la tabla `Inventario` el alias `I`.

Esto lo logro añadiendo luego del nombre de cada tabla la clausula `as` seguida del alias que quiero utilizar. Entonces, en el resto del select, puedo referenciar el campo `id` de la tabla `Ventas` utilizando `v.id`.

En la clausula `on` del `inner join`, voy a relacionar la tabla `ventas` con la de `inventario` mediante el `id` de inventario, que en la tabla ventas asumo es el campo `producto`, de esta forma: `on i.id = v.producto`.

Para que el resultado sea más legible, también coloco algunos alias a las columnas. Por ejemplo, al campo `nombrep` de la tabla `Inventario` le llamaré `nombre_producto`.

```
select   i.nombrep as nombre_producto
       , v.cantidad 
       , i.precio as precio_unitario
       , v.cantidad * i.precio as total
  from Ventas as v
       inner join Inventario as i on i.id = v.producto
```

Considero que con esto, tienes suficiente información para terminar la consulta que devuelva el resultado que buscas.

Un saludo.