# Pequeña duda con query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-10g

Tengo una query en la que me piden

> Cread una consulta que muestre para un atleta determinado las pruebas en las que ha participado. Para cada prueba se debe mostrar la fecha, la descripción de la competición, el resultado almacenado en ‘result’ de Score, así como el nombre del estadio (venue) en que se ha realizado la prueba.
>   Mostrad la consulta SQL. Haced que esta filtre los datos para mostrar únicamente los datos del usuario que tiene por nick ‘eisaza’:

Tengo la query hecha pero no me aclaro como meter el valor del campo `score.score` en `score.result`.

El Modelo de datos es este 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi query es esta;

```
select score.dateresult,competition.compdescription,score.score,venue.venue
from score,competition,venue,webclient,athlete
where athlete.idathlete = score.idathlete
and score.idcompetition = competition.idcompetition
and competition.idvenue = venue.idvenue
and athlete.idathlete = webclient.idwebclient
and webclient.nick ='eisaza';
```

Lo dicho,quiero meter en el campo `result` de `score` el `score` de `score`

Un saludo!!

Comment: No creo que te pidan meter el valor del campo `score.score` en `score.result`. Solo te piden mostrar la columna `score.result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta que tienes esta bastante bien, solo debes incluir el campo `result` de la tabla `score`. Es decir, no tienes que *meter* nada en el campo `result` de `score`, simplemente no incluir `score.score` y en cambio incluir `score.result`.

Tomando como base tu consulta, quedaría asi:

```
select score.dateresult, competition.compdescription, score.result, venue.venue
from score,competition,venue,webclient,athlete
where athlete.idathlete = score.idathlete
and score.idcompetition = competition.idcompetition
and competition.idvenue = venue.idvenue
and athlete.idathlete = webclient.idwebclient
and webclient.nick ='eisaza';
```

Dicho esto, estás escribiendo la consulta con un *estilo* muy antiguo, haciendo lo que se conoce como `join` implícito. Así solían escribirse antes de 1992 (si, **1992**).

El estándar SQL 92, que a estas alturas está soportado por *todos* los motores, introdujo la sintaxis de `join` explícito, que simplifica la manera de escribir las consultas y las hace más fáciles de entender y de mantener.

En esta, básicamente se *separa* las condiciones que *relacionan* las tablas, de las condiciones que filtran los resultados de la consulta. Las condiciones que relacionan las tablas se van escribiendo a medida que se escribe la cláusula `from`.

Por otro lado, la sintaxis permite también expresar el tipo de [`join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21) que vamos a hacer, si es `inner`, `left [outer]`, `right [outer]` o `full outer`.

La consulta equivalente utilizando una sintaxis SQL *moderna* sería algo como esto:

```
select   score.dateresult
       , competition.compdescription
       , score.result
       , venue.venue
  from athlete 
       inner join webclient on webclient.idwebclient = athlete.idathlete
       inner join score on score.idathlete = athlete.idathlete
       inner join competition on competition.idcompetition = score.idcompetition
       inner join venue on venue.idvenue = competition.idvenue
 where webclient.nick = 'eisaza'
```

Comment: Gracias,madre mia como estoy,era eso...Puff tengo la cabeza  ya saturada jejeje.

Comment: Suele suceder, y así es difícil ver hasta los errores más triviales. :)