# Explicacion MySQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Actualmente me encuentro cursando la carrera de análisis de sistemas y al toparme que bases de datos estoy un poco perdido.

¿Me podrían explicar el ejemplo que el profesor nos dio?

```
SELECT e.id AS 'Numero Encargo', cantidad, cl.nombre, co.modelo, e.fecha 
FROM encargos e
    INNER JOIN clientes cl ON cl.id = e.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN coches co ON co.id = e.coche_id
WHERE cliente_id IN (SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE nombre = 'Remis espania');
```

Comment: Creo que lo correcto sería que tus nos digas que es lo que entiendes que hace (_de lo contrario estaríamos haciendo tu tarea_), así nosotros te corregimos (o no) en base a tu respuesta.

Comment: Marcos No estaria entendiendo que funcion comple Inner Join

Comment: ¿Lo has Google-ado? [Acá te dejo](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber) algo que te puede servir.

Comment: Hola, puedes revisar esta pregunta para entender mejor como funciona [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

Del ejemplo que muestras, tenemos las siguientes entidades

- Encargos
- Clientes
- Coches

La relación indicada parece de *Muchos a Muchos* por que la tabla encargos tiene o esta relacionada con coches y y clientes por medio de las llaves foráneas `coche_id` y `coche_id`

Tieniendo un diagrama **similar al siguiente**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué el uso de `INNER JOIN`?

La idea es obtener un conjunto de resultados de la tabla `encargos` cuyas llaves foráneas existan o pertenezcan a algún registro existente de las tablas `coches` y `clientes` descartando por tanto registros de alguna de las 2 que no esten concentrados en la tabla `encargos`.

Dado lo anterior en una relación de muchos a muchos tu puedes almacenar en 1 tercera tabla múltiples veces la o las llaves foráneas que provenga de otra tabla o varias tablas.

Establecido lo anterior, cuando tu profesor hace esto:

```
INNER JOIN clientes cl ON cl.id = e.cliente_id
INNER JOIN coches co ON co.id = e.coche_id
```

Esta buscando obtener los registros de coches y clientes (múltiples de ellos) que estan contenidos en la tabla `encargos` y que existan o coincidan con registros de las otras 2 tablas en cuestión.

Lo anterior se logra igualando `cliente.id` `ON`o con `encargos.cliente_id`

Y lo mismo para el `coche_id`

**Pero como lucen los datos**

Una manera de verlos es:

**tb_encargos**

```
id   cliente_id  coche_id

1       1           2
2       2           3
3       1           4
4       3           2
```

Como puedes observar en este ejemplo, el `id` del cliente 1 tiene mas de un coche asignado, entonces de esta manera podemos almacenar en mas de una vez dicha llave indicando que **muchos clientes puede tener muchos coches y muchos coches pueden estar asignados a muchos clientes**

La última parte donde hace:

```
WHERE cliente_id IN (SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE nombre = 'Remis espania');
```

Es para el filtrado de datos indicando que le muestre toda la información solo donde la llave foránea `cliente_id` en la tabla `encargos` sea igual al id del cliente en la tabla `clientes` cuyo nombre sea `Remis` **aquí lo que hizo fue una subconsulta**

**REFERENCIAS**

- [`JOINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)
- [`Subqueries`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: Es mi respuesta mala del día

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora puede entender mucho mejor!, de verdad gracias.