# Dudas con Funcion Sum Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Mi duda es simple, tengo una tabla de ventas y otra con los tipos de ventas (crédito, contado, instituciones_asociadas) que están relacionadas entre si, y necesito realizar un informe en donde obtener el total vendido por estas categorías, ejemplo: hoy vendí 100 mil contado, 300 mil en crédito.

esto lo logro con un:

```
SELECT TIP_VTA,SUM(TOT_VTA)
FROM VENTAS,TIPVTA 
WHERE VENTAS.TIP_VTA=TIPVTA.COD_VTA 
AND FEC_VTA = '2020-02-05' 
GROUP BY TIP_VTA;
```

En el informe deben aparecer todas las categorías y esta consulta solo me las muestra todas si en la fecha que indique efectivamente se ocuparon estos tipos de venta.

Como podría realizar una consulta donde aparezcan todas las categorías independiente si se utilizaron o no en una fecha especifica. Lo que necesito es que si en la fecha indicada en la consulta no existen ventas crédito, por decir algo, esta aparezca pero con la sumatoria en 0.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Se puede hacer de muchas formas estimado, una de ellas es creando una tabla temporal e ir insertando info por categoría utilizando el "select" de tu pregunta.

Comment: No es lo que busco amigo, que otras opciones tendría?

Comment: Esto se logra con un left join que traiga todo de Ventas y solo la suma que salga de TIPVTA

Comment: considera leer esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que puedes lograr esto utilizando un Join en tu consulta:

```
SELECT TIP_VTA,SUM(TOT_VTA)
FROM VENTAS
RIGHT JOIN TIPVTA 
ON VENTAS.TIP_VTA=TIPVTA.COD_VTA AND FEC_VTA = '2020-02-05' 
GROUP BY TIP_VTA;
```

De esta forma te aseguras de tener las filas de la tabla TIPVTA.

También puedes usar un LEFT JOIN que haría una lectura mas limpia de la consulta:

```
SELECT TIP_VTA,SUM(TOT_VTA)
FROM TIPVTA
LEFT JOIN VENTAS
ON VENTAS.TIP_VTA=TIPVTA.COD_VTA AND FEC_VTA = '2020-02-05' 
GROUP BY TIP_VTA;
```

El LEFT JOIN te permite mostrar todos los registros de la tabla a la izquierda, en este caso TIPVTA y juntarlos con la otra tabla, quedando los valores que no tienen registros vinculados en null o en 0. Con el RIGHT JOIN ocurre lo mismo de forma análoga.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, es lo que buscaba. Saludos

Comment: Mejor un left.. con right, pareceria (a simple vista) que seguis sin traer todas las categorias (porque tip_vta esta del lado de ventas). De paso, considera agregar una explicacion a tu respuesta.

Comment: De nada Benjamin. Saludos.
gbianchi: puse un Right Join porque las tablas las había escrito así, pero es verdad, queda mas intuitivo utilizar un Left Join. 
Ahora actualizo la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el **OR** en la condición de la fecha para que obtengas el resultado que esperas.

```
SELECT TIP_VTA,SUM(TOT_VTA) FROM VENTAS,TIPVTA WHERE VENTAS.TIP_VTA=TIPVTA.COD_VTA AND (FEC_VTA = '2020-02-05' OR FEC_VTA IS NULL OR FEC_VTA <> '2020-02-05') GROUP BY TIP_VTA;
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte

Comment: Lo que necesito es que si en la fecha indicada en la consulta no existen ventas credito, por decir algo, esta aparezca pero con la sumatoria en 0

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido ese where. Trae todos los registros sin importar FEC_VTA

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta con la explicación mas detallada que acabas de dar para que se comprenda mejor el requerimiento.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.