# Nombre de columna por fecha

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy trabajando en postgresql y oracle 11g, quiero asignar nombres a una columna tipo y fecha mayor, me explico:

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
| id  |   fecha    | cod   | descripcion |
|-----|------------|-------|-------------|
| 001 | 2020/01/01 | TP01  | fruta       |
| 001 | 2020/01/02 | TP0X  | comida      |
| 001 | 2020/01/03 | TP03  | verdura     |
| 001 | 2020/01/04 | TP06  | bebestible  |
| 001 | 2020/01/05 | TP0X  | licor       |
| 001 | 2020/01/05 | TP10  | legumbre    |
| 002 | 2020/01/03 | TP03  | verdura     |
| 002 | 2020/01/09 | TP0X  | comida      |
| 002 | 2020/01/08 | TP0X  | licor       |
| 002 | 2020/01/02 | TP10  | legumbre    |
|-----|------------|-------|-------------|
```

Lo que necesito es que el tipo TP0X cambie su descripción para el resto de las filas dependiendo de la fecha, el primer valor que encuentre después lo reemplace por el segundo hacia a delante, el resultado también es agrupado por id, quedando de esta forma:

```
| id  |   fecha    | cod   | descripcion | fix         |
|-----|------------|-------|-------------|-------------|
| 001 | 2020/01/01 | TP01  | fruta       | comida      |
| 001 | 2020/01/02 | TP0X  | comida      | comida      |
| 001 | 2020/01/03 | TP03  | verdura     | comida      |
| 001 | 2020/01/04 | TP06  | bebestible  | comida      |
| 001 | 2020/01/05 | TP0X  | licor       | licor       |
| 001 | 2020/01/05 | TP10  | legumbre    | licor       |
| 002 | 2020/01/02 | TP10  | legumbre    | comida      |
| 002 | 2020/01/03 | TP03  | verdura     | comida      |
| 002 | 2020/01/08 | TP0X  | comida      | comida      |
| 002 | 2020/01/09 | TP0X  | licor       | licor       |
|-----|------------|-------|-------------|-------------|
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué `2020/01/01` cambia su valor si es anterior al primer `TP0X` que aparece? Eso parece contradecir la regla...

Comment: Hola, para `2020/01/01` toma la fecha mas cercana a la primera encontrada. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos? ¿podrías armar un http://sqlfiddle.com/ con este ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución se divide en varios pasos lógicos:

1. El primer *CTE* llamado `MiTabla` simplemente simula la tabla subyacente con los datos que has dado de ejemplo.
2. Dado que no parece haber un campo de tipo secuencial que pueda servir para ordenar de manera fácil los datos, lo primero que hago es crear *al vuelo* (en el primer *CTE* llamado `MiTablaOrdenada`) un campo secuencial (de 1 a N) con el orden que deben tener las filas. Mi sugerencia es, si tu tabla subyacente tiene algún campo que sirva para este efecto, utilizarlo directamente.
3. Luego, en el *CTE* `BaseDescripcion` encuentro todas las filas que servirán para colocar la descripción a utilizar en la columna `Fix`, además aprovecho para encontrar el Número de fila del registro anterior y número de fila del registro siguiente. Para que el algoritmo funcione de manera *independiente* con cada nuevo `id` en la tabla subyacente hago *particiones* en la función de ventana por el campo `id`. Esto hará que el motor deje en `NULL` el campo `FilaAnterior` para cada primera aparición del valor `TP0X` en cada nuevo `id`, lo que es *vital* para construir la solución.
4. Finalmente, armo la solución en el *CTE* `AsignaFix` haciendo la unión de las siguientes consultas:

   1. Obtengo las filas con `cod` `TP0X` directamente desde el *CTE* `BaseDescripcion`, asignando la descripción misma al campo `Fix`. Además me traigo la columna `NumeroFila` que servirá para ordenar el resultado final.
   2. Obtengo las filas que están *después* de cada fila con `cod` `TP0X`, haciendo un [*inner join*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21) de `BaseDescripcion` con `MiTablaOrdenada` obteniendo todas las filas que pertenecen al mismo `id` y están entre el `NumeroFila` de la fila base de la descripción y el `NumeroFilaSiguiente` (sin incluirlos), y asignando la `descripcion` obtenida de `BaseDescripcion` al campo `Fix`.
   3. Finalmente obtengo las filas que, para cada `id`, están antes de la primera aparición del `cod` `TP0X`, también con un *inner join* entre las mismas tablas, solamente ajustando la condición. De manera análoga asigno la `descripcion` obtenida de `BaseDescripcion` al campo `Fix`.

En código, se ve así:

```
with   
MiTabla as (   
select  '001' id, to_date('2020/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') fecha, 'TP01' cod, 'fruta' descripcion from dual   
union all select '001', to_date('2020/01/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'TP0X', 'comida' from dual    
union all select '001', to_date('2020/01/03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP03', 'verdura' from dual    
union all select '001', to_date('2020/01/04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP06', 'bebestible' from dual    
union all select '001', to_date('2020/01/05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP0X', 'licor' from dual    
union all select '001', to_date('2020/01/05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP10', 'legumbre' from dual    
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP03', 'verdura' from dual    
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP0X', 'comida' from dual    
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP0X', 'licor' from dual    
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP10', 'legumbre' from dual   
)   
,   
MiTablaOrdenada as (   
select row_number() over (order by id, fecha, cod) as NumeroFila   
       , id   
       , fecha   
       , cod   
       , descripcion   
  from MiTabla   
)   
,   
BaseDescripcion as (   
select   lag(NumeroFila) over (partition by id order by NumeroFila) FilaAnterior   
       , NumeroFila   
       , lead(NumeroFila) over (partition by id order by NumeroFila) FilaSiguiente   
       , id   
       , fecha   
       , cod   
       , Descripcion   
  from MiTablaOrdenada   
 where Cod = 'TP0X'   
)   
,   
AsignaFix as (   
select NumeroFila, id, fecha, cod, Descripcion, Descripcion Fix   
  from BaseDescripcion   
union all   
select b.NumeroFila, b.id, b.fecha, b.cod, b.Descripcion, a.descripcion   
  from BaseDescripcion a   
       inner join MiTablaOrdenada b on b.id = a.id and b.NumeroFila > a.NumeroFila and b.NumeroFila < coalesce(a.FilaSiguiente, 999999999)   
union all   
select b.NumeroFila, b.id, b.fecha, b.cod, b.Descripcion, a.descripcion   
  from BaseDescripcion a   
       inner join MiTablaOrdenada b on b.id = a.id and b.NumeroFila < a.NumeroFila   
 where a.FilaAnterior is null   
)   
select *   
  from AsignaFix   
 order by NumeroFila
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
NUMEROFILA ID   FECHA     COD   DESCRIPCION   FIX
=====================================================================
1          001  01-JAN-20 TP01  fruta         comida
2          001  02-JAN-20 TP0X  comida        comida
3          001  03-JAN-20 TP03  verdura       comida
4          001  04-JAN-20 TP06  bebestible    comida
5          001  05-JAN-20 TP0X  licor         licor
6          001  05-JAN-20 TP10  legumbre      licor
7          002  02-JAN-20 TP10  legumbre      comida
8          002  03-JAN-20 TP03  verdura       comida
9          002  08-JAN-20 TP0X  comida        comida
10         002  09-JAN-20 TP0X  licor         licor
```

Puedes [probar la solución](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kcmwvb4d6h0ui2cct8y1uy51r) en el sitio de *Oracle en vivo*.

### Aviso de edición

La respuesta ha sido adaptada a raíz de que la pregunta fue editada por el AP. La edición incluye el caso de contar con diversos `id`'s en los datos de entrada y que la lógica explicada por el AP aplica de manera independiente para cada `id`.

La solución original [se encuentra aún disponible](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kbid20tyqfmfnx0mwj9gslkk6) en oracle live.

Comment: me sirvió harto tu código e explicación, pero me surgió un problema, cuando tengo un valor distinto en la columna id, el resultado se desordena, le di muchas vueltas a tu código pero no logré solucionarlo. Al agregar:


`union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP03', 'verdura' from dual 
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP0X', 'comida' from dual 
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP0X', 'licor' from dual 
union all select '002', to_date('2020/01/02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'TP10', 'legumbre' from dual`

Comment: ¿Qué significa que se desordena? El computador siempre va a respetar el orden solicitado en las cláusulas `order by`

Comment: talvez me expresé mal, edité la pregunta principal con el ejemplo para tener mas claridad, pasa que el resultado no los agrupa por id, cuando consulto por un caso en particular por id me resulta bien, pero al agregar un id distinto el resultado no se agrupa por id, no se si lo logro explicar bien, el id es el que manda o agrupa los resultados, Gracias.

Comment: Ya veo, luego de tu edición cual es el tema. Pienso que si comprendieras la lógica de mi respuesta, podrías adaptar el script fácilmente para soportar el caso que se te está presentando y, de verdad, no me gustaría terminar haciendo tu tarea o tu trabajo, pues si bien estamos para ayudar, la idea es ayudar a aprender, no a salir de los compromisos de cada uno, que ya son cosas distintas. Por lo mismo, dejaré mi respuesta tal como está. Si demuestras que te esfuerzas por hacerlo por ti mismo, seguiré por acá si te surge alguna duda.

Comment: @SLinerosC, al final edité mi pregunta, solo por el hecho que había que incluir la cláusula `partition by` que probablemente no conocías aún. Dejo mi comentario anterior, porque creo que sigue siendo válido el pedir que te esfuerces por comprender la solución y no simplemente aplicarla.