# ¿Cómo seleccionar los 3 últimos comentarios de los 3 últimos post?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Quisiera saber como hacer para seleccionar los 3 últimos comentarios de los 3 últimos post hechos en dos tablas distintas relacionadas.

Uso Mariadb 10.3

El script para crear la estructura y datos de ejemplo es:

```
create table posts(
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  primary key (id),
  body text
);

create table coment(
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  primary key (id),
  postID int, 
  foreign key (postID) references posts(id),
  body text
);

insert into posts (body) values 
  ("Post 1"),
  ("Post 2"),
  ("Post 3"),
  ("Post 4");
insert into coment (postID, body) values
  (2, "Segundo222"),
  (2, "Otro comentario"),
  (3, "Holaaaa"),
  (3, "Hola, como estás?"),
  (3, "Bien"),
  (3, ":)"),
  (4, "Prueba");
```

Ejemplo de como quiero que sea el resultado y esquema de ejemplo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d44e6/2)

```
    -- No sé como seleccionar los 3 ultimos comentarios de los 3 ultimos post
    -- El resultado esperado sería:
    -- id | postID | body
    -- 7  | 4      | Prueba
    -- 6  | 3      | :)
    -- 5  | 3      | Bien
    -- 4  | 3      | Hola, como estás?
    -- 2  | 2      | Otro comentario
    -- 1  | 2      | Segundo222
    
    select * from coment order by id desc;
```

Comment: Incluye siempre la información de la estructura como parte de tu pregunta. El SQL Fiddle está genial, pero la idea es que la información completa de la pregunta esté en SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que usas `MariaDB 10.3x`, podemos aprovechar algunas mejoras introducidas que son comunes en otras bases. Hablo particularmente de la función [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) y las [common table expresion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/). Con esto, la idea será hacer dos numeradores uno por antiguedad del `post` y otro por la de los `post/comment`, finalmente deberíamos seleccionar solo aquellos inferiores a 3.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT c.postID,
       p.body AS 'post_body',
       c.id,
       c.body AS 'comment_body',
       rn_post,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC, c.id DESC) AS rn_coment
       FROM (SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn_post
                    FROM posts 
            ) p
              
       INNER JOIN coment c
         on p.id = c. postID
)
SELECT * 
       FROM CTE 
       WHERE rn_coment <= 3 
             AND rn_post <=3 
       ORDER BY rn_post, rn_coment
```

Puedes consultar este [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5f58b864c8ea66ea88db71e76d761d03)

Comment: Al final use esta algo modificada, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Te explico mi solución:

1. Obtengo en una tabla derivada solamente los últimos 3 posts, valiéndome de la cláusula `limit` del `select` anidado, básicamente así:

   ```
    select posts.id 
      from posts
     order by posts.id desc
     limit 3
   ```
2. En otra tabla derivada, obtengo todos los comentarios de las entradas, y para cada una voy numerando los comentarios (1, 2, 3) en orden inverso a su inserción, en el campo `CommentReverseNum`.

   Para ello me basé en la sección **MySQL `ROW_NUMBER` – adding a row number to each group** del tutorial [**MySQL `ROW_NUMBER`, This is How You Emulate It**](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) (en inglés).

   La consulta de manera independiente luciría algo así:

   ```
    set @comment_number := 0;

    select   @comment_number :=
               case
                 when @postID = postID then @comment_number + 1
                 else 1
               end as CommentReverseNum
           , @postID := postID postID
           , id
           , body
      from coment
     order by postID, id desc
   ```
3. Pongo cada una de las consultas anteriores en *tablas derivadas* dentro de una consulta y hago un [`inner join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21) entre las mismas. Finalmente, en la cláusula `where` de esta consulta principal limito para traer solamente los últimos 3 comentarios de cada entrada.

La solución final es:

```
set @comment_number := 0;

select   orderedComments.id
       , orderedComments.postID
       , orderedComments.body
  from (select posts.id 
          from posts
         order by posts.id desc
         limit 3
       ) lastposts
       inner join (
        select   @comment_number :=
                   case
                     when @postID = postID then @comment_number + 1
                     else 1
                   end as CommentReverseNum
               , @postID := postID postID
               , id
               , body
          from coment
         order by postID, id desc
       ) orderedComments
       on orderedComments.postID = lastposts.id
 where orderedComments.CommentReverseNum <= 3
 order by orderedComments.postID desc, orderedComments.CommentReverseNum;
```

Que devuelve este resultado:

```
id      postID  body
-------+-------+---------------------
7       4       Prueba
6       3       :)
5       3       Bien
4       3       Hola, como estás?
2       2       Otro comentario
1       2       Segundo222
```

La solución quedó también en [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d44e6/163/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
(select * from coment where postID =4 order by id desc limit 3)
union
(select * from coment where postID =3  order by id desc limit 3)
union
(select * from coment where postID =2 order by id desc limit 3);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Eso no afecta al rendimiento? Y si en ves de solo 3 requiero 10 ¿tampoco afectaría al rendimiento?

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas simple es proceder de esta forma:

- Selecciona de la tabla `posts` las columnas deseadas
- Para el caso de los comentarios al no tener una columna de fecha, filtraremos los últimos por el `id` generado en cada registro de ellos

  - En este caso podemos usar `GROUPO_CONCAT` para que los 3 últimos comentarios queden en una celda
  - Dentro de la función `GROUP_CONCAT` indicamos que queremos la columna `body` de la tabla `coment` y lo ordenamos de forma descendente para obtener primero los últimos registros hechos
- Como ambas tablas se encuentran relacionadas por el `postID` entonces podemos hacer un `INNER JOIN`
- Al final agrupamos los resultados y ordenamos de forma descendente limitando a 3 para obtener las últimas 3 publicaciones

La consulta entonces pudiera lucir así:

```
SELECT posts.id, 
       posts.body, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(coment.body ORDER BY postID DESC) AS Comentarios
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN coment ON posts.id = coment.postID
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.body
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Y con una salida así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sirve; pero ahora... Si necesito mas datos de la tabla de comentarios como la fecha o dirección de un archivo adjunto. Creo que esto no es suficiente

Comment: Las fechas de los comentarios? Bueno no te ofrecí esa parte por qué tu tabla no posee más datos y no puedo saber que más requieras

Comment: En sí, necesito todos los datos de la tabla comentarios.