# Consulta SQL INNER JOIN de 2 datos de una tabla a otra

Tags: mysql, sql

Me ocupa lo siguiente:
Tengo una tabla que posee 2 columnas que tienen el mismo origen que son plataforma_origen y plataforma_destino ellas almacenan solo los id de las distintas plataformas.

```
**TABLA GESTION**
id
usuario
plataforma_origen
plataforma_destino
```

Los ids se originan de la siguiente Tabla

```
**TABLA PLATAFORMA**
id
plataforma
```

Lo que quisiera es hacer una sentencia SQL que me permita obtener como resultado algo como

```
id
usuario
plataforma_origen
plataforma_destino
```

pero que las columnas

```
plataforma_origen
plataforma_destino
```

muestren los nombres que correspondan en la TABLA PLATAFORMA
He intentado con INNER JOIN pero solo lo he logrado hacer funcionar con una sola relacion dejo el SQL que he podido hacer funcionar a medias

```
SELECT *
FROM gestion
INNER JOIN plataforma
ON plataforma.id = gestion.plataforma_origen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer [`join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21) dos veces a la misma tabla para obtener la descripción de ambas plataformas, utilizando *alias* para distinguir entre una y otra.

En resumen:

```
SELECT   gestion.id
       , gestion.usuario
       , po.plataforma as plataforma_origen
       , pd.plataforma as plataforma_destino
  FROM gestion
       INNER JOIN plataforma as po on po.id = gestion.plataforma_origen
       INNER JOIN plataforma as pd on pd.id = gestion.plataforma_destino
```

Esto suponiendo que siempre existan las plataformas. Puedes cambiar de `inner join` a `left join` si alguno de los campos de relación tiene valores nulos y te interesa obtener ese registro en el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pl.plataforma
FROM plataforma AS pl
INNER JOIN gestion AS ge ON pl.id = ge.plataforma_origen OR (pl.id = ge.plataforma_destino)
```

Lo otro que se me ocurre es esto:

```
SELECT pl.plataforma
FROM plataforma AS pl
INNER JOIN gestion AS ge ON pl.id = ge.plataforma_origen AND (pl.id = ge.plataforma_destino)
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor edita y agrega una explicación

Comment: Gracias BetaM..

Comment: Gracias por responder pero esta solucion propuesta no me funciona ya que en la tabla solo tengo 3 datos y al correr tu SQL me da como 6 resultados duplicando los resultados

Comment: Le hice unas modificaciones, tal vez con un OR o un AND funcionen.