# Valor repetido en filas consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

un agrado saludar.
Favor ayuda/orientación como obtener este resultado deseado :

TABLA MONTO:

```
NOMBRE  MONTO
 A1     100   
 A2     300
 A3     100
 A4     200
```

TABLA OPERACIONES :

```
NOMBRE     OPERACION
 A1       OPERACION 1
 A1       OPERACION 2
 A1       OPERACION 3
 A1       OPERACION 4 
 A2       OPERACION 1
 A2       OPERACION 2
 A3       OPERACION 3
```

**TABLA DESEADA :**

```
NOMBRE   OPERACION     VALOR MONTO 
A1       OPERACION 1     100
A1       OPERACION 2     NULL
A1       OPERACION 3     NULL
A1       OPERACION 4     NULL
A2       OPERACION 1     300
A2       OPERACION 2     NULL
A2       OPERACION 3     NULL
```

En la tabla deseada necesito vincular el monto de cada nombre a la primera operación, pensando que pueden ser muchas operaciones solo debe asignárselo a la primera operación, luego a las operaciones siguientes para el mismo nombre debe ser null o cero.

Desde ya les agradezco su apoyo, gracias.

Comment: ¿La operación siempre empieza con el número 1?

Comment: Hola, gracias. No, puede cambiar...lo que importa es que siempre sea la primera de cada nombre...gracias.

Comment: Hola, justamente pensando que podría cambiar había escrito [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383015/21). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Los puedes resolver con un `CASE` para indicar en que fila iría el `MONTO`, en tu ejemplo parece que son aquellas filas donde `OPERACION = 'OPERACION 1'`

```
SELECT O.NOMBRE,
       O.OPERACION
       CASE O.OPERACION = 'OPERACION 1' THEN MONTO ELSE NULL END AS MONTO
       FROM OPERACIONES O
       LEFT JOIN MONTO M
            ON M.NOMBRE = O.NOMBRE
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que las *operaciones* no iniciarán necesariamente en `'OPERACION 1'`, sino que podrían tener otro valor, la siguiente consulta te asocia el valor a la operación más baja que se encuentre:

```
;with
OperacionNumerada as (
select   op.nombre
       , op.operacion
       , row_number() over (partition by nombre order by operacion) NumFila
  from Operacion op
)
select   op.Nombre
       , op.operacion
       , m.monto
  from OperacionNumerada op
       left join Monto m on m.nombre = op.nombre and op.NumFila = 1
 order by op.Nombre, op.NumFila;
```

Para hacerlo, primero calculo el número de fila que corresponde a cada operación y luego hago un [`left join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21) de este resultado con la tabla `monto` solo para las filas que tienen el número 1, que representa la primera operación encontrada.

El resultado obtenido es:

```
Nombre  operacion       monto
A1      OPERACION 1     100
A1      OPERACION 2     NULL
A1      OPERACION 3     NULL
A1      OPERACION 4     NULL
A2      OPERACION 1     300
A2      OPERACION 2     NULL
A3      OPERACION 3     100

(7 rows affected)
```