# Como leer dato de una tabla sql con foreign key de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, tablas

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una tabla donde tiene una llave foranea que es de la misma tabla, esta es para poder hacer jefes a los mismos empleados, la tabla es la siguiente:[image: Tabla_Empleado]

entonces, mi duda es, como puedo saber el nombre del jefe, hasta ahora hice este intento pero en la columna de jefes me sale null:

select id_empleado, nombre_empleado, (select nombre_empleado from empleado where jefe=id_empleado) from empleado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy similar a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/450423/21) por lo que supongo que [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/450435/21) te será igualmente útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una tabla con una relación con ella misma se conoce también como una **relación recursiva** y se usa mucho para **modelar jerarquías** como en el ejemplo que planteas, tu consulta podría quedar de esta forma:

```
select e1.nombreEmpleado as Empleado, e2.NombreEmpleado as Jefe
from empleado e1 inner join empleado e2 on e1.idJefe = e2.idJefe
```

Aquí se enlaza la tabla con ella misma a traves de un **inner join**, como es la misma tabla se establecen **alias de e1 y e2** para diferenciar. El **inner join** se usa para juntar tablas teniendo en cuenta ciertas condiciones, aquí la condición es que los **idJefe** de **e1** y **e2** sean iguales, por último se hace una selección de los campos que nos interesan, la selección devuelve el nombre del empleado pero un nombre será el del jefe y otro el del subordinado por eso a uno se le da como **alias Empleado** y al otro **Jefe**.

Comment: me funciono bastante bien, enserio muchísimas gracias 