# Ampliar resultados de mi consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Me ocupa lo siguiente
Tengo la siguiente sentencia SQL

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(billetera.monto) AS Monto_a_favor FROM users INNER JOIN billetera ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id GROUP BY ID
```

Esto me da como resultado todos los usuarios que esten en la tabla `users` que en algun momento hayan tenido saldo en la tabla `billetera`, pero me gustaria que el resultado fuera el siguiente:

Mostrar todos los datos de la tabla `users` pero que en la columna `Monto_a_favor` los que tangan saldo 0 o saldo negativo tambien aparezcan, intente con el siguiente codigo pero no logro dar con la solucion

```
SELECT users.*, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (SUM(billetera.monto) AS Monto_a_favor
FROM users
INNER JOIN billetera ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id GROUP BY ID)  > 0 THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'Monto_a_favor',
FROM users
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta original esta bien, solo le falta arreglar la parte del join.

Como bien se explica [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/324), cada tipo de join hace una cosa diferente...

Como en tu caso vos queres todo lo que esta a la izquierda, sin importar si esta o no a la derecha, entonces tenes que cambiar un `inner join` (que solo trae lo que esta en los dos lados), por un `left join` (que trae todo lo de la izquierda, y solo lo relacionado de la derecha)

```
SELECT 
    users.*, 
    SUM(billetera.monto) AS Monto_a_favor 
FROM 
    users 
LEFT JOIN 
    billetera ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id 
GROUP BY ID
```