# Obtener registros que contengan uno o más valores en una columna en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de canciones, tengo otra tabla de etiquetas y una última tabla con la relación entre las canciones y las etiquetas.

Necesito obtener toda aquella canción que contenga el tagID de una o más etiquetas, pero debe devolver sólo un resultado por canción, sin duplicados.

Siguiendo las fotos adjuntadas necesitaría obtener el registro 590 porque cumple la condición de tener las etiquetas 4 y 7. Y no recibir dos registros de 590, sólo uno.

He probado esta consulta pero me devuelve varios registros. Y cuando cambio OR por AND no me devuelve nada porque estoy comparando la misma columna. ¿Alguna solución?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tracks_tags 
WHERE tagId LIKE "%4%" OR tagId LIKE "%7%"
```

Dejo un ejemplo de mis tablas.

**TABLA TRACKS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TABLA TAGS**

[image: TABLA TAGS]

**TABLA TRACKS_TAGS CON LA RELACIÓN DE CANCIONES Y ETIQUETA**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con esa QUERY daría de resultado las 3 filas que aparece en la tabla de TRACKS_TAGS

Comment: Te explico el porque al usar OR está dando igual si es uno o es el otro, en cambio en la publicación de Jonatan indica 4 y 7 es decir un AND pero claro un AND no se puede usar ya que es por columnas y no por filas, debería usar ```IN (4, 7)``` pero aún no sé exactamente si es lo que el busca.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado q esperas?

Comment: Jonatan podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ACTUALIZADO, La consulta anterior que propuse como solución estaba escrita de manera rápida y no me parecía del todo correcto.

La solución a tu problema es:

1. Comparamos el ID de las canciones con la tabla **tracks_tags**
2. **TG.tagID** in(4, 7) indicas los tagsId que desees comprobar simultáneamente
3. Agrupamos el resultado por Tracks.id para evitar duplicados.
4. Según los tags consultados devolverá 2 resultados por cada una de las canciones entonces según el tamaño del array lo agrupará.

````
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tracks_tags AS TG,
    tracks AS T
WHERE
    T.id = TG.trackId
    AND
    TG.tagId IN (4,7)
GROUP BY T.id
HAVING count(distinct TG.tagId) = 2; /* TAMAÑO TOTAL DEL ARRAY DE TG.tagId().... */```
````

Comment: Sí, aunque estoy reajustando la QUERY ya que fue lo que me vino a la cabeza

Comment: Actualizado, creo que es lo que busca, si hay otra solución será bienvenido, pero estoy totalmente seguro que es su solución.

Answer (score 0):

Analiza esta posible solución, quizá te sea útil en lo que deseas hacer:

```
select trackId, group_concat(cast(tagId as varchar), ', ') as Etiquetas from TRACKS_TAGS
group by trackId
```

La clave está en usar la **función de agregación group_concat** y la **cláusula group by**, de esta forma mostrarás todas etiquetas que corresponden a una misma canción, separando las etiquetas por el caracter **','**. Obtendrías algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres las canciones que tengan las dos etiquetas,
la suma (agregación condicional) de etiquetas buscadas debe ser 2, suponiendo que las etiquetas no se repiten para cada canción.

```
SELECT tt.trackId
     , t.title
  FROM tracks_tags tt
    JOIN tracks t
      ON t.id = tt.trackId
  GROUP BY tt.trackId
         , t.title
  HAVING sum( tagId in(4,7) ) = 2
```

Para tres etiquetas cambiaría:

```
  HAVING sum( tagId in(4,7,9) ) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo para proponer un enfoque alternativo, yo lo haría con las funciones JSON de mysql. Sean `tags_array` un campo de tipo JSON (específicamente, un array json)  proveniente de una subconsulta, y `array_buscado` un arreglo de ids que queremos filtrar.

La función `JSON_CONTAINS(tags_array, array_buscado)` retorna verdadero cuando todos los elementos de `array_buscado` están presentes en `tags_array`.

Poblando la BBDD con canciones y tags, tal que

```
SELECT song_name, 
       song_id, 
       CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id), ']') tag_ids,
       CAST(JSON_ARRAYAGG(tag_name) as JSON) tagnames
FROM songs 
JOIN tag_song USING (song_id)
JOIN tags USING (tag_id)
GROUP BY song_name,song_id
```

Se vea como:

| song_name | song_id | tag_ids | tagnames |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| despacito | 4 | [2] | ["español"] |
| muñeca de trapo | 2 | [1,2] | ["triste","español"] |
| penelope | 3 | [1,2,3] | ["triste","español","clásica"] |
| Sultans of swing | 5 | [3,4] | ["clásica","anglo"] |
| yesterday | 1 | [1,3,4] | ["triste","clásica","anglo"] |

Entonces:

```
WITH tagged AS (
    SELECT song_name, 
           song_id, 
           concat('[', GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id), ']') tag_ids,
               cast(JSON_ARRAYAGG(tag_name) as JSON) tagnames
    FROM songs 
    JOIN tag_song USING (song_id)
    JOIN tags USING (tag_id)
    GROUP BY song_name,song_id
)
SELECT * from tagged WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tagnames,'["clásica","triste"]')
```

Mostrará solamente yesterday y penélope (las únicas clásicas **Y** tristes en la lista).

Si quisieras aplicar el equivalente a un `OR`, y estuviésemos en MySQL 8, la función `JSON_OVERLAPS` listaría todas las canciones donde al menos un elemento está entre los buscados. O sea, se habría listado además "Sultans of Swing" porque cumple con al menos un elemento (anglo).

Lo que me gusta de la sintaxis es que podrías encapsular la subquery en una vista, y buscar en ella directamente, sin tener que hacer la búsqueda y luego la agregación una y otra vez, cosa que puede ser ineficiente si la agregación es costosa. Pasar de un conjunto de AND a uno de OR sólo afecta a una función. No hay que añadir ni quitar cláusulas, sino que todo se delega mediante el argumento.

obviamente también se puede buscar por ID

```
 SELECT * FROM tagged WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tag_ids,'[3,1]')
```

pero quise mostrar la coincidencia por slugs porque tu capa de negocios recibirá o al menos podrá computar los slugs, mientras que los ID son desconocidos en esa parte del pipeline.

<kbd>[dejo un fiddle funcionando](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/0)</kbd>

PD: Por supuesto el orden de los elementos es irrelevante. Buscar `["triste","clásico"]` es igual a `["clásico","triste"]`

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las canciones que tienen el tag 4 y 7, podrías hacer 2 [`INNER JOIN`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/16597) (*uno por cada tag*)

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT T.* 
    FROM tracks AS T

    INNER JOIN tracks_tags AS TT1
        ON TT1.trackId = T.id
        AND TT1.tag_id = 4

    INNER JOIN tracks_tags AS TT2
        ON TT2.trackId = T.id
        AND TT2.tag_id = 7
```

Answer (score -1):

Si necesitas obtener todas las canciones que tengan al menos una etiqueta, esto te debería funcionar:

```
SELECT distinct T.artist,T.title FROM TRACKS T join TRACKS_TAGS TT on T.id = TT.trackId;
```

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre incluir una breve descripción de lo que haces diferente, por qué y cómo usarlo

Comment: @Javier El punto y coma se necesita según el contexto; en ésta respuesta ni abona ni quita.