# Realizar consulta a tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

Quisiera que me pudieran ayudar a realizar una consulta en base de datos en 3 tablas relacionadas.

Tengo tres tablas:

- movimientos
- Despachador
- Trabajadores
- comunas

[image: Relación entre las tablas]

Si me pueden ayudar a realizar la consulta en la tabla movimientos.

Seseo mostrar `id`, `fecha`, `numeropedido`, `numeroventa`, `tipoventa`,

Es para un almacén en donde se arman pedidos entonces.

Si no se entiende bien lo explico de forma conceptual:

Tengo la tabla movimientos que es donde se guardan todos los movimientos números de pedidos y esas cosas. Cada pedido se envía a una dirección, que en este caso es la relación con `id_comuna`, y ese pedido lo arma una persona que es el `id_armado`.

Ese pedido lo embala otra persona que es una misma que está en la tabla `trabajadores` y, además, ese pedido es enviado por un despachador.

Lo que deseo es en vez de mostrar los `id_comuna`, `id_empleado`, `Id_despachador`.

Que me mostrase el `nombre`, en vez de los `id`. Es para mostrarlo en un formulario, ya que si lo muestro tal cual solo me mostrará los números únicos de cada tabla y no me sirve.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Qué consultas SQL has probado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para orientarte un poco léete esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join), sobre **JOIN**, **LEFT JOIN**, **RIGHT JOIN** y **FULL JOIN**.

Te aconsejo que hagas pruebas, respecto sobre lo que has leído en el artículo, es como más se aprende, piensa que realmente las preguntas sin código no son bienvenidas.

Podrías obtener el nombre de tus *columnas* con relación usando por ejemplo: `` LEFT JOIN `comuna` AS c ON m.id_comuna = c.id ``, y obtendrás el nombre de comuna según el id que tengas en movimientos.

**Posible ejemplo:** 
*Según el ejemplo de tus tablas*

```
SELECT 
          m.id,
          m.fecha,
          m.numeropedido,
          m.numeroventa,
          m.tipoventa,
          c.comuna,
          a.nombre AS `nombre_armado`,
          e.nombre AS `nombre_embalado`,
          d.nombre AS `nombre_despachador`
     FROM `movimientos` AS m
LEFT JOIN `comuna`      AS c ON m.id_comuna = c.id
LEFT JOIN `trabjadores` AS a ON m.id_armado = a.id
LEFT JOIN `trabjadores` AS e ON m.id_embalado = e.id
LEFT JOIN `despachador` AS d ON m.id_despachadores = d.id
```

Comment: Eres el mejor excelente muchas gracias super perfecto !

Comment: Me alegro amigo, suerte en tu proyecto, saludos.