# Relacion de tablas de departamento y propietarios

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

es primera vez que tengo que hacer tablas relacionadas.
Tengo dos tablas departamentos y propietarios.

### departamentos:
id int(11) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
nrodepto varchar(10) not null,
id_prop int(11) not null,

---

### propietarios:
id int(11) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
nombre varchar(25) not null,
apellidos varchar(25) not null,

---

solo he puesto los campos necesarios.
tengo esta consulta:
SELECT d.*, p.id, p.nombre, p.apellidos FROM departamentos d INNER JOIN propietarios p WHERE d.id  = p.id

Tengo esta relación en la tabla propietarios

usuarios_ibfk_1 id departamentos id_prop CASCADE CASCADE
usuarios_ibfk_1 id departamentos id_prop RESTRICT RESTRICT
usuarios_ibfk_1 id departamentos id_prop RESTRICT RESTRICT no se porque VSCode hace esta segunda relación siendo que es igual a la anterior.

Mi problema es que cuando listo los departamentos en el campo id muestra el id del propietario y no el id del departamento. El caso es que un propietario puede tener mas de un departamento.

Mi consulta es ¿como hacer que muestre cada departamento y el nombre de cada dueño. en este momento tengo 6 propietarios y 8 departamentos?.

Así como esta la consulta en datatable me muestra 6 registros y no muestra el segundo  departamentos que tiene los propietarios.

Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Comment: Eso es por que estas usando INNER JOIN, o JOIN simple, esto solo te retornará las registros en los cuales coincidan ambos, deberías usar un LEFT JOIN.

Comment: ``SELECT d.*, p.id, p.nombre, p.apellidos FROM departamentos d LEFT JOIN propietarios p ON p.id=d.id``

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/16597)

Answer (score 2):

Haz este pequeño cambio y a continuación te explico por qué no funciona tu propuesta:

```
SELECT
    d.*,
    p.id,
    p.nombre,
    p.apellidos
FROM
    departamentos d
INNER JOIN propietarios p
ON d.id_prop = p.id;
```

En realidad tanto `WHERE` como `ON` cumplen la misma función. Con `ON` la consulta es más eficiente, pero dan el mismo resultado. El error de concepto lo tienes al combinar por los campos `id`.

Tú quieres combinar cada propiedad con su propietario, y la forma de identificar al propietario desde la propiedad es guardando su `id` en el campo `id_propietario`. Si combinas directamente por los campos `id`, combinarás el primer departamento con el primer propietario, el segundo con el segundo, y así sucesivamente, si es que coinciden sus `id`... Vamos, que te estás dedicando a sortear departamentos. Los casos en los que no se te combinan es porque habrá huecos en los autonuméricos.

Con respecto a lo que llamas relaciones, que realmente son restricciones de tipo clave ajena o FK, no afectan a las consultas. Únicamente se definen para impedir que le asignes un departamento a un propietario que aún no hayas registrado.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y bienvenido a SO y al mundo de las bases de datos. Sigue intentando cosas y preguntando por lo que no te salga como esperas, es la forma más rápida de aprender.

Comment: Gracias por responder y el ejemplo.

Hice los siguiente:
$sql = "SELECT d.*, p.id, p.nombre, p.apellidos FROM deptos d LEFT JOIN propietarios p ON d.id = p.id";

y mostro:
[![Departamento con LEFT y id][1]][1]


Si pongo la consulta asi, con id_prop.
"SELECT d.*, p.id, p.nombre, p.apellidos FROM deptos d LEFT JOIN propietarios p ON d.id_prop = p.id";

Muestra esto:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvzqy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwrAF.png

Comment: ¿Y es lo que esperabas?

Comment: No, en la imagen 1, los dos primeros registros dice null, y en la imagen 2, se repiten los id 1 y 5, lo que me da a entender es que esta mostrando los ID de los Propietarios que son 6 y debiera mostrar los id de los departamentos que son 8

Comment: Eso depende de los datos que hayas registrado en la tabla departamentos. Si modificas la pregunta mostrando algún datos de prueba, podremos comprobar si la consulta está funcionando correctamente. Puedes obtener un volcado en SQL con phpMyAdmin->exportar

Comment: David JP, como hago para subir 2 archivos sql, deptos y propietarios?

Comment: Copia el código fuente y pega en modo texto. Después seleccionas y pulsas Ctrl+k para darle formato de código. No hace falta que copies todos los datos del `INSERT`, con unos cuantos para hacer las pruebas es suficiente

Answer (score 0):

Tabla deptos:

```
CREATE TABLE `deptos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nrounidad` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_prop` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ubicacion` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `habitaciones` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `banos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `habitantes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `metros` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `nota` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_prop` (`id_prop`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `deptos` VALUES
(1,'107A',1,'Primer Piso Torre A',3,2,3,'62',1,'En Buen Estado, habitado por los dueños'),
(2,'701A',2,'Septimo Piso Torre A',2,2,2,'54',1,'Buen estado'),
(3,'101A',1,'Primer Piso Torre A',2,1,2,'45',1,'Buen Estado'),
(4,'106A',3,'Primer Piso Torre A',3,2,4,'65',1,'Buen estado'),
(5,'108A',5,'Torre A',1,1,2,'45',1,'Prueba'),
(6,'109A',4,'Torre A',2,1,3,'55',1,'Prueba'),
(7,'201A',6,'Torre A',3,2,4,'55',1,'Prueba'),
(8,'209A',5,'Torre A',2,1,3,'55',1,'Prueba');
```

Tabla propietarios:

```
CREATE TABLE `propietarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `rut` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `fono` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `nota` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_nac` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rut` (`rut`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `propietarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `deptos` (`id_prop`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `propietarios` VALUES
(1,'Claudio','González Soto','6.285.306-9','claudio.gonzalez@gmail.com','48d42c247f103aeae693fda22aef475060bc6344','322 596 330',1,'Registro de Usuario','1952-06-14'),
(2,'MIGUEL','VALLE','77.777.777-7','macpolicar@gmail.com','580ef36f361f5a39a66ce81a3c9d715da887c82e','963425869',1,'Registro Administrador','2016-10-06'),
(3,'Ana','Armijo','55.555.555-5','ana@ana.cl','580ef36f361f5a39a66ce81a3c9d715da887c82e','555555555',1,'Registro Administrador','1960-10-01'),
(4,'Raul','Jorquera','22.222.222-2','raul@info.cl','580ef36f361f5a39a66ce81a3c9d715da887c82e','6515489',1,'Registro Administrador','2002-12-05'),
(5,'José','Bueras','11.111.111-1','jose@gmail.com','580ef36f361f5a39a66ce81a3c9d715da887c82e','95125874',1,'Registro Administrador','2008-10-25'),
(6,'Rita','Rios','33.333.333-3','rita@info.com','580ef36f361f5a39a66ce81a3c9d715da887c82e','75315985',1,'Registro Administrador','2010-12-02');
```

Comment: Eso es, pero editando la pregunta, no abriendo una nueva respuesta, e incluyendo los `create table` :)

Comment: Eso es, pero editando la pregunta: Disculpas no sabia como hacerlo, pero ya voy aprendiendo y ya edite y agregue a la Create table

Comment: Aquí estamos en la respuesta, la pregunta es la primera que aparece :)

Comment: No, he puesto el INNER JOIN y DEFT JOIN, y de ninguna manera da el resultado que espero.
Con INNER solo muestra 6 registros, que son los propietarios registrados, y no muestra los propietarios y su segundo departamento.
Con LEFT  muestra los 10 departamentos que hya registrados hasta ahora, y los propietarios que tienen mas de un departamento muestra sus nombre como NULL.
SELECT d.*, p.id, p.nombre, p.apellidos FROM deptos d LEFT JOIN propietarios p ON d.id = p.id
Y si cambio d.id por d.id_prop, muetra todo pero se repiten los ID del propietario en vez del ID de los Deptos,

Comment: Acabo de descubrir que el inconveniente es problema de datatables, osea que yo no lo estoy haciendo bien al listar los registros en datatable.
Ejecute la consulta por consola de debian, (No uso phpmyadmin), y ahi muestra bien los datos. por ende voy a tener que investigar en datatbale

Comment: "SOLUCIONADO", cambie el ID de la tabla deptos por id_depto modifique los archivos implicados y todo funcionó como lo necesitaba.
Gracias por la ayuda prestada