# Obtener el ultimo registro de una tabla X dentro de un select de una tabla Y

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Tengo 2 tablas **COMPRA** y **CONSULTA** .En la tabla **compra** tengo varios registros que son únicos por ID y no se repiten.  En la tabla **consulta** tengo todos los registros de las personas que vienen a ver si su compra ya esta lista.

[image: Tabla compra]

[image: Tabla consulta]

Un ejemplo.
En mi tabla compra tengo el siguiente registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi tabla consulta tengo los siguientes registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver la  primera persona que fue a consultar su compra fue juan y la ultima fue julio.

quiero realizar un select a la tabla compra y que muestre el nombre de la ultima personas que esta registrada de la tabla consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes valerte de un [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para construir la solución a este problema.

Por ejemplo, ejecutar los siguientes pasos:

- Hacer un join de ambas tablas, lo que nos dará varias filas por compra (tantas como consultas haya habido)
- En este mismo numerar las filas de cada compra en orden cronológico inverso, según la fecha de la consulta. Para ello podemos valernos de la función de ventana [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- Finalmente hacemos un select sobre este primer CTE y nos quedamos solamente con las filas que tienen número 1, que serán las de la última consulta.

El código vale más que mil palabras:

```
with
ConsultaCompraEnOrden as (
select   Compra.id
       , Compra.NroCompra
       , Compra.Monto
       , Consulta.FechaConsulta
       , Consulta.NombreApellido
       , row_number() over (partition by Compra.id order by Consulta.FechaConsulta desc) as NumeroLinea
  from Compra
       left join Consulta on Consulta.idCompra = Compra.id
)
select id, NroCompra. Monto, FechaConsulta, NombreApellido
  from ConsultaCompraEnOrden
 where NumeroLinea = 1
```

En el ejemplo estoy haciendo un [`left outer join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21) entre las tablas, lo que incluirá en el resultado las compras que aún no hayan recibido ninguna consulta. Si quires incluir solamente las compras que hayan tenido consultas, cambia el join por un `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

Otra manera de hacerlo:

```
select c.Id, c.NroCompra, q.NombreApellido, c.Monto
from Compra c
LEFT JOIN Consulta q on c.Id = q.IdCompra
where q.FechaConsulta = (
  select max(FechaConsulta)
  from Consulta
  where IdCompra = c.Id
)
```

Usas un `LEFT JOIN` para unir las dos tablas en función del Id. Luego, utilizas una subconsulta para obtener la fecha de la última consulta realizada para cada compra haciendo uso de la función `max`.

Comment: Si por casualidad hay dos registros con la misma `FechaConsulta`, esta fallará, en el sentido que imprimirá dos registros para la compra. Por otro lado el AP no especifica qué hacer en ese caso, aunque lo más común es que quiera verse solo una vez.

Comment: @jachguate Tienes razón. En ese caso ningún enfoque funcionaría. Por que la función ROW_NUMBER junto a OVER debe tener ORDER BY y al usar el ORDER BY en la fecha, si bien es cierto que tu enfoque no muestra registros duplicados tampoco muestra el último registro, suponiendo que hubiesen fechas duplicadas. Y en este caso tampoco se puede ordenar por 'IdConsulta' por que el 'Id' de la consulta es el 'Id' de la compra. Entonces obligado el AP tendría que agregar un campo adicional por ejemplo 'IdConsulta' auto incrementable?

Comment: Si, es cuestión de qué tipo de fallo es preferible. Si hay dos registros con la misma fecha, mi solución arbitrariamente toma uno de los dos como _último_, por lo mismo que no hay otro campo que ayude a definir con precisión cuál es este. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta, es ¿**qué significa último**?

No has puesto la definición de tablas, pero la columna fecha, parece un varchar y no un tipo de dato fecha, por tanto el concepto de último puede llevarte a errores. Esto es independiente de cualquier solución que apliques.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta, es, si *Juan* también hubiera tenido datos el *25-04*, ¿a quíen te debería de devolver la consulta? ....a 1 ....a los dos....a cual de los dos...

Otra solución es aplicar el [operador apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/).

**Escenario**

```
Create table Compra (id varchar(10), NroCompra varchar(100), Monto varchar(25));

Create table Consulta (idCompra varchar(10), NombreApellido varchar(25), Fecha VARCHAR(10));

Insert into Compra(id, NroCompra, Monto)
values
('01','10-24D','$/250');

Insert into Consulta(idCompra, NombreApellido, Fecha )
values
('01','JOSE','11-04-23'),
('01','JUAN','10-04-23'),
('01','JULIO','25-04-23');
```

**Solución:**

```
SELECT c.id as idCompra
     , c.NroCompra
     , fx.NombreApellido
     , c.Monto
FROM COMPRA C 
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP(1) Con.NombreApellido
                FROM CONSULTA Con
                WHERE Con.idCompra = c.id
            ORDER BY cast(fecha as date) desc
        ) fx;
```

[image: Res]

Para unir ambos conjuntos usamos el alias (en el caso `Con` alias de la tabla `Consulta`, se une con la `tabla Compra`, en el caso `C` directamente en el `Where Con.idCompra = c.id`).

**Nota:** En cualquier solución, tienes que revisar si lo que devuelve `Select Fecha From consulta order by Fecha`, o `Select Fecha from consulta order by cast(fecha as date)` encaja con el orden que esperas. Esto no te lo podemos indicar, porque el conjunto de datos que has puesto es muy pobre y no sabemos como anotas los días. Por ejemplo, si anotas el 9 o 09.