# Consulta SQL, agrupación en una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

demandas:

| ID_USUARIO | ID_DEMANDA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

usuarios:

| ID_USUARIO | NOMBRE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan |

entrevistas:

| ID_ENTREVISTA | ID_ENTREVISTADOR_ABOGADO | ID_ENTREVISTADOR_RRHH | OTROS_ENTREVISTADORES | ID_DEMANDA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Notario | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |  | 1 |

entrevistadores:

| ID_ENTREVISTADORES | NOMBRE_ENTREVISTADOR | ID_GRUPO_ENTREVISTADOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jose | 1 |
| 2 | Marta | 2 |
| 3 | Pedro | 3 |

grupo_entrevistadores:

| ID_GRUPO_ENTREVISTADORES | NOMBRE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JURIDICO |
| 2 | RRHH |

```
La consulta es la siguiente:
SELECT usuario.NOMBRE,usuario.APELLIDOS, entrevistadores1.NOMBRE_ENTREVISTADOR AS JURIDICO, entrevistadores2.NOMBRE_ENTREVISTADOR AS RRHH,entrevistas1.OTROS_ENTREVISTADORES AS OTROS
FROM dbsiax.entrevistas entrevistas1
JOIN demanda ON demanda.ID_DEMANDA = entrevistas1.ID_DEMANDA
JOIN usuario ON demanda.ID_USUARIO = usuario.ID_USUARIO
JOIN entrevistas entrevistas2 ON demanda.ID_DEMANDA = entrevistas2.ID_DEMANDA
JOIN entrevistadores entrevistadores1 ON entrevistas1.ID_ENTREVISTADOR_ABOGADO = entrevistadores1.ID_ENTREVISTADOR
JOIN entrevistadores entrevistadores2 ON entrevistas1.TIENE_ENTREVISTADORES_RRHH = 'SI' AND entrevistas1.ID_ENTREVISTADOR_RRHH = entrevistadores2.ID_ENTREVISTADOR
WHERE entrevistas1.TIENE_ENTREVISTADORES_ABOGADOS = 'SI'
AND (entrevistas1.TIENE_ENTREVISTADORES_RRHH = 'SI' OR entrevistas1.TIENE_OTROS_ENTREVISTADORES = 'SI')
AND entrevistas1.FECHA_ENTREVISTA BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-03-17';
```

El objetivo es que no me devuelva todas las entrevistas que tiene una demanda, sino todos los entrevistadores que participaron en las entrevistas de una demanda.

Algo así tendría que ser el resultado:

| NOMBRE_USUARIO | ENTREVSITADORES_JURIDICO | ENTREVISTADORES_RRHH | ENTREVISTADORES_OTROS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Jose | Marta, Pedro | Notario |

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es porque tu DB lo necesita asi, o es para mostrar en algun sistema??? si es lo ultimo, deja de pelearte con la DB y hacelo directamente en ese sistema.

Comment: Nota que `null in(null)` resulta `null`.

Comment: Por favor, publica la estructura de las tablas como texto legible, no como imagen. Considera también quitar todos los campos que no son esenciales para entender el problema de la consulta, que resulta pesada de leer así. Un [mcve] sería lo ideal. Si lo haces, déjame un comentario y con gusto veo de escribir una respuesta.

Comment: Lo he actualizado y ahora creo que se visualiza mejor @jachguate

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución se basa en el uso de [CTE's](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/), que se realizan con la cláusula [`with`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

***Queja:*** Antes de empezar, decir que la pregunta no tiene un [ejemplo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), por lo que he tenido que eliminar los campos que no existen en la estructura de la misma y adoptar nombres de tablas o campos de manera arbitraria, pues no coinciden los nombres de las tablas y campos publicadas con la consulta en si.

***Solución:*** Ahora si, y para no variar, mi estrategia es *dividir* el problema, utilizando el enfoque lógico que voy a explicar a continuación, para conquistar finalmente el resultado esperado.

1. Se puede observar que, al haber una doble relación con la tabla `entrevistas`, y por tanto un doble *join*, si hacemos todo en una única consulta los registros se van a duplicar, triplicar y más.
   Para evitar esa duplicación, consideramos armar la *lista* de entrevistadores de cada *rol* por separado, para ensamblarlos en la solución final.
2. Un mismo *entrevistador* pudo haber participado en distintas entrevistas en una misma demanda. Aquí, a falta de claridad, estoy asumiendo que cada persona debe aparecer una sola vez en la lista, independientemente de cuantas veces haya participado, pues entiendo que se necesita la lista de entrevistadores y no un detalle de las entrevistas.
3. Vamos a solucionar primero el último tema mencionado, en tres CTE's llamados  `cEntrevistasJuridico`, `cEntrevistasRRHH` y `cEntrevistasOtros`. Su estructura es muy simple, básicamente una sentencia `select distinct` para obtener los *id's* de los distintos entrevistadores en cada uno de los primeros dos roles y los distintos valores en el caso del tercero (que no tiene relación con las tablas).
4. Luego, por separado para cada *rol* vamos a *armar* una lista de los entrevistadores valiéndonos del a función [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), lo que nos dará una lista separada por comas. Los CTE's que hacen esta parte se llaman `cEntrevistadoresJuridico`, `cEntrevistadoresRRHH` y `cEntrevistadoresOtros`
5. Finalmente, ensamblamos la consulta que dará el resultado final, cuidándonos de hacer [left outer join](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21) con la tabla de demandas, para que estas aparezcan aún cuando no tengan entrevistas.

Como siempre, el código dice más que mil palabras:

```
with
cEntrevistasJuridico as (
select distinct entrevistas.id_demanda, entrevistas.id_entrevistador_abogado
  from entrevistas 
)
,
cEntrevistasRRHH as (
select distinct entrevistas.id_demanda, entrevistas.id_entrevistador_rrhh
  from entrevistas 
)
,
cEntrevistasOtros as (
select distinct entrevistas.id_demanda, entrevistas.otros_entrevistadores
  from entrevistas 
 where otros_entrevistadores is not null
)
,
cEntrevistadoresJuridico as (
select cEntrevistasJuridico.id_demanda, group_concat(entrevistadores.nombre_entrevistador) entrevistadores_juridico
  from cEntrevistasJuridico
       JOIN entrevistadores ON cEntrevistasJuridico.ID_ENTREVISTADOR_ABOGADO = entrevistadores.ID_ENTREVISTADOR
 group by cEntrevistasJuridico.id_demanda
)
,
cEntrevistadoresRRHH as (
select cEntrevistasRRHH.id_demanda, group_concat(entrevistadores.nombre_entrevistador) entrevistadores_rrhh
  from cEntrevistasRRHH
       JOIN entrevistadores ON cEntrevistasRRHH.id_entrevistador_rrhh = entrevistadores.ID_ENTREVISTADOR
 group by cEntrevistasRRHH.id_demanda
)
,
cEntrevistadoresOtros as (
select id_demanda, group_concat(otros_entrevistadores) otros_entrevistadores
  from cEntrevistasOtros
 group by id_demanda
)
select   usuarios.nombre
       , cEntrevistadoresJuridico.entrevistadores_juridico
       , cEntrevistadoresRRHH.entrevistadores_rrhh
       , cEntrevistadoresOtros.otros_entrevistadores
  from demandas
       inner join usuarios on usuarios.id_usuario = demandas.id_usuario
       left join cEntrevistadoresJuridico on cEntrevistadoresJuridico.id_demanda = demandas.id_demanda
       left join cEntrevistadoresRRHH on cEntrevistadoresRRHH.id_demanda = demandas.id_demanda
       left join cEntrevistadoresOtros on cEntrevistadoresOtros.id_demanda = demandas.id_demanda
```

He preparado un [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jE4oYQJZhzE3s58SyC5GQR/0) con los mismos datos de prueba, dónde puede observarse que el query devuelve los resultados esperados:

| nombre | entrevistadores_juridico | entrevistadores_rrhh | otros_entrevistadores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Jose | Marta,Pedro | Notario |

---

Como expliqué al inicio, la consulta no incluye campos que no aparecían en el esquema, queda como tarea al interesado adaptar la solución a su esquema real.

OJO: La solución requiere mySQL 8.0 o superior, pues los CTE's no están soportados en versiones anteriores, que a estas alturas son obsoletas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo había conseguido, pero tu solución es mucho más ordenada.

Comment: Nunca es tarde para implementarla, jeje. Me alegra ser de ayuda. :)