# Consulta en PSQL sobre distancias de aeropuertos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy tratando de hallar los aeropuertos más cercanos a uno en específico, con los datos obtenidos desde un dataframe con la siguiente información:

```
routes(airline_code, airline_id, source_airport_code, source_airport_id, destination_airport_code, destination_airport_id, codeshare, stops, equipment)
```

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT p1.name, (((p2.latitude - p1.latitude) + (p2.longitude - p2.longitude))^(1/2)) AS distancia
FROM airports p1, airports p2
WHERE p2.name = 'Pdte. Carlos Ibañez del Campo Airport'
ORDER BY distancia ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Pero el problema que tengo, es que esto me entrega que todas las distancias son iguales a 1.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar un inner join. Saludos

Comment: @Jakintsu, ¿cómo utilizar _inner join_ resuelve el problema planteado? o por ¿qué la _recomendación_?

Comment: Hola @jachguate. Creo que con un inner join sería más eficiente, que el producto cartesiano  de dos tablas. Al realizar el inner join (o cross join, left join ..), ya que nos permite asociar las tablas en base a un campo común. Un saludo y gracias por tus aportes

Comment: El cross join es un producto cartesiano. Para encontrar el aeropuerto más cercano, si no hay una tabla que almacene las distancias, no hay de otra que hacer un producto cartesiano.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que se puede ver, estás tratando de obtener la *distancia euclideana*, pero no estás aplicando bien la fórmula.

Esta se deriva del teorema de pitágoras, dónde tratamos de obtener la hipotenusa a partir de dos catetos.

La fórmula general es

```
h² = c1² + c2²
```

Luego, la fórmula de la hipotenusa sería:

```
h = √(c2² + c2²)
```

Luego, nuestros catetos serían: el primero la distancia que hay entre latitudes, y el segundo la distancia que hay entre longitudes.

De allí se deriva el **primer error** de tu fórmula, pues no estás elevando los catetos al cuadrado.

El **segundo error** es que, en el segundo cateto estás restando la longitud del segundo aeropuerto de ella misma, con lo que el resultado de la operación siempre será cero.

Corrigiendo esto, la fórmula de la distancia podría quedar así:

```
((p2.latitude - p1.latitude)^2 + (p2.longitude - p1.longitude)^2)^(1/2)
```

Dicho esto, la distancia euclideana te da la distancia entre dos puntos en un plano, pero estos puntos que estás utilizando se encuentran sobre una superficie curva, la de tierra, por lo que las distancias que estás obteniendo son una aproximación, y una no muy buena.

Finalmente, te recomiendo también cambiar la cláusula `from` de tu consulta, el estándar SQL 92 introdujo una sintaxis que es más explícita para indicar la relación entre las tablas, y tú estás utilizando una forma anterior a este estándar, es decir, estás escribiendo la consulta como se hacía hace más de 30 años.

Para hacer un producto cartesiano, la cláusula from podría ser:

```
FROM airports p1 
     cross join airports p2
```

Es un cambio pequeño, pero las consultas se entienden mucho mejor cuando se escriben con esta sintaxis *moderna*, sobre todo en el caso de [inner y outer joins](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21).