# Error 512 SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado.

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure F_FacturaES, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 53]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

El problema está en que tengo que traer la infomacion de la tabla `IBT1` aunque sea mas de un valor.

Este es mi procedimiento:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[F_FacturaES]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Dockey int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Select F.DocEntry,F.DocDate,F.DocNum,
        (Select top 1 (D1.Street + ', '+D1.Block+', '+D1.City)Address
            From OCRD C1
                Inner Join CRD1 D1 on C1.CardCode = D1.CardCode and D1.AdresType = 'B'
            Where C1.CardCode = F.CardCode
        ) Address,
        F.CardCode,F.CardName,C.AddID NRC,F.DocTotal[Total Factura], V.SlpName, CP.PymntGroup,C.VatIdUnCmp,[dbo].[CantidadConLetra] (F.docTotal) Letras,F.DiscSum DescTotal,
        F1.ItemCode,F1.CodeBars,F1.Dscription,F1.Quantity,F1.Price,F1.GPBefDisc PrecioBruto,F1.TaxCode,F1.LineTotal,F1.LineTotal *1.13 GTotal,F1.VatSum,F1.PriceBefDi,F1.DiscPrcnt,
        (Case When F1.TaxCode = 'EXE' then F1.LineTotal end) VExento,
        (Case when F1.TaxCode ='IVA' then F1.LineTotal end) VGrabado,
        (Case when F1.TaxCode ='IVA' then F1.LineTotal *1.13 end) VGrabadoCF,
        (Case when F1.TaxCode ='NS' then F1.LineTotal end) VNOSujeto,
        (select Name from [@SOCIOSGIRO] where Code = C.U_TypeGiroSN)Giro,
        C.CardFName Establecimiento,f1.baseentry,
        (Select top 1 DocNum From ODLN where DocEntry =F1.BaseEntry ),
        (select top 1 T1.DistNumber
            FROM IBT1 AS T0
                left join OBTN AS t1 ON t0.BatchNum=t1.DistNumber 
            where t0.BaseType=15 and t0.Quantity>0 and BaseEntry = f1.BaseEntry and BaseType=15 and T1.ItemCode = f1.ItemCode) Lote,
        (select T1.ExpDate
        FROM IBT1 AS T0
            left join OBTN AS t1 ON t0.BatchNum=t1.DistNumber 
        where t0.BaseType=15 and t0.Quantity>0 and BaseEntry = f1.BaseEntry and BaseType=15 and T1.ItemCode = f1.ItemCode) ExpDate
    From OINV F
        Inner join INV1 F1 on F.DocEntry = F1.DocEntry
        Inner Join OCRD C on F.CardCode = C.CardCode
        Inner Join NNM1 N on F.Series = N.Series    
        Inner Join OITM A on F1.ItemCode = A.ItemCode
        Inner Join OSLP V on F.SlpCode = V.SlpCode
        Inner Join OCTG CP on F.GroupNum = CP.GroupNum
    Where F.DocEntry = @Dockey
END
```

Comment: Hay dos sentencias en subconsultas `select` que potencialmente pueden devolver más de un registro y generar ese error. `select Name from ...` y `select T1.ExpDate ...`. Estas sentencias, usadas como expresiones, deben devolver exactamente un registro. Si devuelven 2 o más, el motor no puede decidir cual incluir, y tampoco son parte de un _join_ como para actuar de esa forma, de allí que se genera el error.

Comment: si es que de hecho deben devolver mas de uno en caso de que existan, entonces mi pregunta es como lo soluciono para que me devuelva mas de uno en caso de existir

Comment: Al igual que el motor, no sabría responder esa pregunta sin saber lo que pretendes lograr. Tus opciones son a)elegir tu uno de los registros o indicar que utilice uno cualquiera, por ejemplo, como haces ya con otras sentencias donde tienes `select top 1` (agregas un `order by` si quieres ser tu quien elija). b) Si quieres usar todos los registros que devuelve, no hacer la sub-consulta como una expresión, sino hacer un _join_ que genere el resultado e incluir el/los campos dentro del select (donde ahora está la/las subconsulta/s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener todas las filas de la tabla `IBT1` dentro del resultado de la consulta, lo que tienes que hacer es añadir dicha tabla dentro de la cláusula `from` como otro *join*.

Conceptualmente sería de cambiar esto:

```sql
select   Tabla1.Campo1
       , Tabla2.Campo2
       , (select Campo3 from Tabla3 where Tabla3.Campo3 = Tabla1.Campo3)
  from Tabla1
       inner join Tabla2 on Tabla2.Campo = Tabla1.Campo
```

A esto:

```sql
select   Tabla1.Campo1
       , Tabla2.Campo2
       , Tabla3.Campo3
  from Tabla1
       inner join Tabla2 on Tabla2.Campo = Tabla1.Campo
       left join Tabla3 on Tabla3.Campo3 = Tabla1.Campo3
```

Debes elegir el [tipo de join](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21) que vas a hacer. Yo he dejado un *left* join, para que en caso que Tabla3 no devuelva registros, aún así aparezca en el resultado con la columna `Campo3` en null.

Traduciendo esto a tu consulta, voy a asumir que en las dos sub-consultas dónde involucras la tabla `IBT1` quieres procesar ambos registros y que has puesto `top 1` en la primera en un intento de lograr el resultado, por lo que voy a eliminar las dos sub-consultas y a tomar en ambos casos los campos directamente de la tabla en el *join*.

```
select   F.DocEntry
       , F.DocDate
       , F.DocNum
       , (select top 1 (D1.Street + ', '+D1.Block+', '+D1.City)Address
            From OCRD C1
                 inner join CRD1 D1 on C1.CardCode = D1.CardCode and D1.AdresType = 'B'
           where C1.CardCode = F.CardCode
         ) Address
       , F.CardCode
       , F.CardName
       , C.AddID NRC
       , F.DocTotal [Total Factura]
       , V.SlpName
       , CP.PymntGroup
       , C.VatIdUnCmp
       , [dbo].[CantidadConLetra] (F.docTotal) Letras
       , F.DiscSum DescTotal
       , F1.ItemCode
       , F1.CodeBars
       , F1.Dscription
       , F1.Quantity
       , F1.Price
       , F1.GPBefDisc PrecioBruto
       , F1.TaxCode
       , F1.LineTotal
       , F1.LineTotal *1.13 GTotal
       , F1.VatSum
       , F1.PriceBefDi
       , F1.DiscPrcnt
       , (Case When F1.TaxCode = 'EXE' then F1.LineTotal end) VExento
       , (Case when F1.TaxCode ='IVA' then F1.LineTotal end) VGrabado
       , (Case when F1.TaxCode ='IVA' then F1.LineTotal *1.13 end) VGrabadoCF
       , (Case when F1.TaxCode ='NS' then F1.LineTotal end) VNOSujeto
       , (select Name from [@SOCIOSGIRO] where Code = C.U_TypeGiroSN)Giro
       , C.CardFName Establecimiento
       , f1.baseentry
       , (Select top 1 DocNum From ODLN where DocEntry =F1.BaseEntry )
        --aquí los campos en lugar de sub-consultas
        , OBTN.DistNumber Lote
        , OBTN.ExpDate
   from OINV F
        inner join INV1 F1 on F.DocEntry = F1.DocEntry
        inner join OCRD C on F.CardCode = C.CardCode
        inner join NNM1 N on F.Series = N.Series    
        inner join OITM A on F1.ItemCode = A.ItemCode
        inner join OSLP V on F.SlpCode = V.SlpCode
        inner join OCTG CP on F.GroupNum = CP.GroupNum
        --aquí el join de la ex sub-consulta
         left join IBT1 
                    left join OBTN ON IBT1.BatchNum = OBTN.DistNumber 
           on IBT1.BaseType = 15 
          and IBT1.Quantity > 0 
          and BaseEntry = f1.BaseEntry
          and BaseType = 15 
          and OBTN.ItemCode = f1.ItemCode
    where F.DocEntry = @Dockey;
```

**Advertencia:** He hecho el join según lo que puedo ver en las sub-consultas. He hecho un `left join` del resultado de otro `left join`. Dado que no conozco la estructura y hay campos sin calificar, no me atreví a dejar todos los joins al mismo nivel, pero probablemente el plan sea mejor si se hace ese cambio.

Hay un par de cosas que mejorar:

- Hay campos sin calificar, lo cual es un riesgo durante el mantenimiento del sistema, pues el query puede dejar de funcionar si de pronto aparece un campo con el mismo nombre en alguna de las otras tablas de la consulta.
- La condición del campo `BaseType` esté duplicada

Comment: Hola gracias por tomarte el el tiempo en contestar, pero me dan los siguientes errores

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
The multi-part identifier "IBT1.BatchNum" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
The multi-part identifier "OBTN.DistNumber" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
The multi-part identifier "IBT1.BaseType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
The multi-part identifier "IBT1.Quantity" could not be bound.

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
Ambiguous column name 'BaseEntry'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
Ambiguous column name 'BaseType'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 59

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Mi plan era quitar los alias de las tablas y al final lo hice a medias. Ahora debiera estar terminando.  La idea es que entiendas la idea. Yo estoy escribiendo el código aquí mismo en la respuesta, ya que no tengo forma de probarlo.  Espero que si se cuela algún error tú, que si puedes probarlo y has entendido la idea, pongas algo de tu parte y trates de resolverlo también

Comment: Bro eres un genio, en serio no se que  hubiera hecho sin tu ayuda.