# Como realizar un select donde puede colocar 2 valores de la pero misma columna referenciada a otro en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando de realizar un select donde toda la información se encuentra en la misma columna, tengo 2 parámetros de referencia el de la columna subproducto y la referencia hacia el id, lo que busco es tratar de simplificar la información para que los subproductos se puedan acoplar con los productos, no se si me puedan ayudar

Datos en la tabla:

```
Id          Productos  Cantidad    SubProducto Referencia a Id
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
10          Producto_1 1           Si          20
20          Producto_2 1           No          NULL
30          Producto_3 3           No          NULL
40          Producto_4 4           Si          50
50          Producto_5 4           No          NULL
60          Producto_6 5           Si          30
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Id   Productos  Cantidad Referencia a id SubProductos Cantidad
---- ---------- -------- --------------- ------------ -----------
10   Producto_1 1        20              Producto_2   1
40   Producto_4 4        50              Producto_5   5
60   Producto_6 6        30              Producto_3   3
```

Imagen de referencia original:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En SQL es perfectamente válido utilizar varias veces una misma tabla en la cláusula `from`, que es de dónde parte la solución a este problema. Una vez las agregas, tratas cada una de ellas de la misma manera como si fuese una tabla distinta.

Para que esto funcione es obligatorio utilizar alias todas las veces que aparezca la misma tabla, excepto la primera, que si se puede dejar sin alias (también se le puede poner). Esto es necesario para poder referirnos a las columnas sin ambigüedad, por esta misma razón siempre deberán ir calificadas en todas las partes de la sentencia.

Es decir, si tenemos la columna "Productos" en la tabla, para incluirla debemos indicar a cuál de las apariciones de la tabla en la cláusula from nos referimos.

Un ejemplo básico sería hacer el producto cartesiano de la tabla por si misma:

```sql
select t1.Productos as Productos_de_MiTabla_como_t1, t2.Productos as Productos_de_MiTabla_como_t2
  from MiTabla t1
       cross join MiTabla t2
```

Podemos hacer cualquier [tipo de `join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21) entre las apariciones de la tabla (exactamente como si se tratase de dos tablas distintas).

No has dicho el nombre de tu tabla, por lo que de aquí en adelante se llamará `MiTabla`.

He preparado un ejemplo que resuelve tu problema. Para construir esta solución:

- Incluyo la tabla la primera vez y le asigno el alias `ProductoMaster`
- Sobre esta añadiré en la cláusula `where` una condición para obtener las filas que tengan `Si` en la columna `SubProducto`
  , Luego hago un *inner join* con la misma tabla, que esta vez tendrá el alias `SubProducto` utilizando la condición `ProductoMaster.[Referencia a id] = SubProducto.Id`.
- Finalmente solo incluir las columnas pertinentes de cada aparición de la tabla en el resultado.

Para adaptar la consulta, sustituye el nombre de la tabla `MiTabla` en sus dos apariciones por su nombre real.

```sql
select   ProductoMaster.Id
       , ProductoMaster.Productos
       , ProductoMaster.Cantidad
       , ProductoMaster.[Referencia a id]
       , SubProducto.Productos SubProductos
       , SubProducto.Cantidad CantidadSub
  from MiTabla ProductoMaster
       inner join MiTabla SubProducto on SubProducto.Id = ProductoMaster.[Referencia a id]
 where ProductoMaster.SubProducto = 'Si'
 order by ProductoMaster.Id
```

Algunas anotaciones finales:

- El resultado no puede tener dos columnas con el mismo nombre: `Cantidad`; por lo que a la segunda le estoy llamando `CantidadSub`.
- Estoy trayendo las cantidades que están almacenadas en la tabla en ambas columnas, realmente no sé de dónde salen las cantidades de tu ejemplo y tampoco lo explicas.

  Por ejemplo, en la segunda fila, las cantidades almacenadas son 4 para el producto principal y 4 para el sub-producto, pero tú esperas obtener 4 y 5, mientras que en la tercera fila, la Cantidaddevolverá 5, que es la cantidad almacenada pero tu esperas obtener 6.

  Si no es un error que cometiste al escribir el ejemplo, ya tú te encargas de hacer las adaptaciones/cálculos que haga falta para obtener dichos valores.
- Tu diseño tiene redundancia entre la columna `SubProducto` y `[Referencia a Id]`. Usualmente trato de evitar esto al diseñar una base de datos, pues no solo es innecesario, sino que puede dar lugar a errores si no se programa cuidadosamente todos los casos en que se agrega o se pierde una relación entre un producto master y un sub-producto. Estos errores provocarían que un usuario vea resultados inconsistentes. Por ejemplo, podríamos toparnos con el caso de un producto que tenga `Si` en dicha columna, pero no tenga una `[Referencia a Id]` válida. Por la condición del `where` yo podría esperar ver dicha fila en el resultado final, pero el `inner join` la eliminaría. Esto genera costos innecesarios también, pues un programador promedio puede tardar horas en detectar la fuente del problema, que se pudo haber evitado con un mejor diseño.

Mis resultados son:

```
Id  Productos  Cantidad Referencia a id SubProductos CantidadSub
--- ---------- -------- --------------- ------------ -----------
10  Producto_1 1        20              Producto_2   1
40  Producto_4 4        50              Producto_5   4
60  Producto_6 5        30              Producto_3   3
```

[Ejemplo en db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jRbiiWAw)