# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre FROM Books RIGHT JOIN Authors y FROM Authors LEFT JOIN Books?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, join

He estado aprendiendo sentencias de JOIN en SQL y me tope con un problema que creo poder resolver de dos disntitas maneras, este problema lo encontré en SoloLearn y quisiera discutirlo aquí, está en inglés.

> **Number of Books**
>
> You are working on the library database, which contains the Books and
> Authors tables. Columns of the Books table: **id, name, year,
> author_id**
>
> Columns of the Authors table: **id, name**
>
> Write a query to get the author names and the number of books they
> have in the Books table.
>
> Note that some authors do not have any books associated with them. In
> this case, the result needs to include their names and have 0 as the
> count. The count column should be called books in the result.
>
> Hint: Sort the result by the number of books from highest to lowest.

Ahora en español

> Número de Libros
>
> Estás trabajando en la base de datos de una biblioteca, la cual
> contiene las tablas Books y Authors. Columnas de la tabla Books: > id,
> name, year, author_id.
>
> Columnas de la tabla Authors: id, name.
>
> Escribe una consulta para obtener los nombres de los autores y el
> número de libros que tienen en la tabla Books.
>
> Ten en cuenta que algunos autores no tienen ningún libro asociado. En
> este caso, el resultado debe incluir sus nombres y contar con 0. La
> columna de conteo debe llamarse books en el resultado.
>
> Pista: Ordena el resultado por el número de libros de mayor a menor.

La respuesta es esta:

```
SELECT A.name, COUNT(B.id) as books
FROM Books AS B RIGHT JOIN Authors AS A
ON B.author_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY books DESC;
```

Pero entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente, en el proceso de resolución pensé que podría usar también una forma alterna del JOIN, algo como cambiar el RIGHT JOIN por LEFT JOIN pero también cambiar las tablas para tener el mismo resultado.

```
SELECT A.name, COUNT(B.id) as books
FROM Authors AS B LEFT JOIN Books AS A
ON B.author_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY books DESC;
```

Obtendré los mismos resultados si cambio de LEFT JOIN a RIGHT JOIN y cambiar las tablas? Pregunté a ChatGPT y me dijo que no pero al mismo tiempo me dijo que sí (ya sabemos que para lo lógico no sirve jaja), pero aún así copiaré por acá la respuesta

La diferencia entre FROM Books RIGHT JOIN Authors y FROM Authors LEFT JOIN Books radica en el orden en que se consideran las tablas y cómo se manejan los registros que no tienen coincidencias.

FROM Books RIGHT JOIN Authors: En este caso, se tomarían todos los registros de la tabla de la derecha (Authors) y se combinan con los registros coincidentes de la tabla de la izquierda (Books). Si hay registros en la tabla de la derecha (Authors) que no tienen coincidencias en la tabla de la izquierda (Books), se mostrarán como NULL.

FROM Authors LEFT JOIN Books: Aquí se tomarían todos los registros de la tabla de la izquierda (Authors) y se combinan con los registros coincidentes de la tabla de la derecha (Books). Si hay registros en la tabla de la izquierda (Authors) que no tienen coincidencias en la tabla de la derecha (Books), se mostrarán como NULL.

GRACIAS.

Comment: No habría diferencia (además de ser un psicópata que usa `RIGHT JOIN`) si hubieras mantenido los alias de cada tabla. Como los modificaste, en efecto los resultados que vas a obtener pueden ser diferentes

Comment: no es tan común entonces hacer uso de RIGHT JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Los resultados serían exactamente ser los mismos si mantienes la lógica del query, pero no es tu caso, pues has cambiado los alias, pero no lo has hecho de manera consistente.

Veamos la sentencia original, solo voy a

- re-indentarla para que sea más legible (al menos para mi)
- Estandarizarla, pues no en todas las bases de datos puedes usar un alias de columna en la cláusula `order by`, pero diría que en todas puedes usar la columna como tal. Al menos en las 2 o 3 que conozco, si se puede.

```
SELECT   A.name
       , COUNT(B.id) as books
  FROM Books AS B 
       RIGHT JOIN Authors AS A ON B.author_id = A.id
 GROUP BY A.name
 ORDER BY COUNT(B.id) DESC;
```

Esta sentencia produciría exactamente los mismos resultados, pues solo he cambiado de lado las tablas y la dirección del *outer join*.

```
SELECT   A.name
       , COUNT(B.id) as books
  FROM Authors AS A
       LEFT JOIN Books AS B ON B.author_id = A.id
 GROUP BY A.name
 ORDER BY COUNT(B.id) DESC;
```

Como nos explica la respuesta a [¿cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40/21) en el diagrama de Venn que replico al final de esta respuesta, **Left y Right [outer] join son exactamente lo mismo, pero de diferente lado**.

Otra sentencia igualmente válida, cambiando los alias, sería hacerlo de manera consistente:

```
SELECT   B.name
       , COUNT(A.id) as books
  FROM Authors AS B
       LEFT JOIN Books AS A ON A.author_id = B.id
 GROUP BY A.name
 ORDER BY COUNT(A.id) DESC;
```

Debo decir que este último cambio me hace mucho ruido, pues mientras `A` es un excelente alias para `Authors` y `B` para `Books`, no lo son cambiados y es más fácil cometer errores si los alias no significan nada o no tienen una buena relación con el nombre de la entidad.

Ahora, la sentencia que publicaste luego de cambiar right por left:

```
SELECT A.name, COUNT(B.id) as books
FROM Authors AS B LEFT JOIN Books AS A
ON B.author_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY books DESC;
```

Si la observas detenidamente, tu error está en haber cambiado el alias de las tablas en la cláusula from, pero no en otras partes de la consulta. Entonces, mientras la sentencia original recupera el nombre del autor, la tuya trae el nombre del libro, suponiendo que la tabla `books` tenga un campo `name`, y mientras la sentencia original cuenta cuántos libros tiene ese autor, la tuya cuenta cuántos autores tiene ese libro.

Además, probablemente falle, porque trata de relacionar las tablas por un campo  `author_id` en la tabla de autores con el `id` del libro.

Para que se vea más claramente, voy a quitar los alias y sustituirlos por el nombre de la tabla:

```
SELECT Books.name, COUNT(Authors.id) as books
FROM Authors LEFT JOIN Books 
ON Authors.author_id = Books.id
GROUP BY Books.name
ORDER BY books DESC;
```

¿Se ve claro ahora?

Finalmente, la gráfica prometida.
[image: Explicación visual de joins]
Imagen [SQL_Joins_es.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SQL_Joins_es.svg) de [jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate)/[Arbeck](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Arbeck), compartida bajo licencia [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en).

Comment: De ser posible, por favor modificá la imagen para que tenga un fondo blanco. En el modo oscuro se dificulta bastante leer el texto.

Comment: @padaleiana tienes toda la razón, no me había dado cuenta que la imagen es transparente. Lamentablemente no es de mi autoría, sino de wikimedia. Veré de hacer una propia y vendré a cambiarla cuando la tenga. Gracias por la anotación.

Comment: Lo de los alias fue un error de dedo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @padaleiana finalmente, después de perder algún trabajo con ella, pude publicar otra gráfica. Espero que esta se vea bien. Un saludo. :)

Comment: ¡Ahora sí! Gracias :D