# ¿Por qué me restringe la consulta en php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy enfrentando un problema con una consulta SQL en mi proyecto web y necesito su ayuda para solucionarlo.

El problema radica en que tengo una consulta SQL que debería traer todos los registros de una tabla en función de ciertos criterios, pero solo me está mostrando los registros donde id_yate = 11. Esta no es la funcionalidad que estoy buscando, necesito que muestre todos los registros que correspondan al id_capitan pero no importa que id_yate tenga y que su estado sea "No Asignado"

```
<?php
// Iniciar la sesión
session_start();

$id_usuario = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// Verificar si el usuario ha iniciado sesión
if (!isset($_SESSION['firstname'])) {
    header('Location: ../login.php');
    exit;
}

// Incluir el archivo de configuración de la base de datos
require '../config/database.php';

// Consulta la tabla Capitanes para obtener el id_capitan correspondiente al id_usuario
$sql_id_capitan = "SELECT id_capitan FROM Capitanes WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";
$result_id_capitan = $conn->query($sql_id_capitan);

if (!$result_id_capitan) {
    echo "Error en la consulta: " . $conn->error;
    exit;
}

// Obtén el valor de id_capitan
$id_capitan = $result_id_capitan->fetch_assoc()["id_capitan"];


$sql_asignaciones = "SELECT a.id, CONCAT(duenos.nombres, ' ', duenos.apellidos) AS owner_name, y.nombre_yate, a.estado, c.Foto, y.id_yate AS id_yate, r.id_reserva AS id_reserva, a.id_capitan
                    FROM asignacion_capitanes a
                    JOIN Capitanes c ON c.id_capitan = a.id_capitan
                    JOIN Yates y ON y.id_yate = a.id_yate
                    JOIN Usuarios duenos ON duenos.id_usuario = y.id_dueno
                    JOIN reservas r ON r.id_yate = y.id_yate
                    WHERE a.id_capitan = $id_capitan
                    ORDER BY a.id DESC";



$result_asignaciones = $conn->query($sql_asignaciones);

if (!$result_asignaciones) {
    echo "Error en la consulta de asignaciones: " . $conn->error;
    exit;
}

// Esta función se llama para cargar y mostrar los datos en tiempo real
function obtenerDatosAsignaciones() {
    global $result_asignaciones;

    // Crear una variable para almacenar el contenido HTML
    $contenidoHTML = '';

    // Dentro de tu bucle while
    while ($row = $result_asignaciones->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Construye el HTML y agrégalo a la variable $contenidoHTML
        $contenidoHTML .= '<form method="POST" action="procesar_asignacion_capitan.php">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="cuadro">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="circle">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<img style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="' . $row["Foto"] . '" alt="Profile Picture">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="contenedor">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="columna1">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="texto-container">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h5>Assignment ID: </h5>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["id"] . '</h6>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="texto-container">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h5>Owner: </h5>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["owner_name"] . '</h6>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="columna2">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="texto-container">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h5>Yacht:</h5>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["nombre_yate"] . '</h6>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<div class="texto-container">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h5>Status:</h5>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["estado"] . '</h6>';
         $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["id_capitan"] . '</h6>';
         $contenidoHTML .= '<h6>' . $row["id_yate"] . '</h6>';


        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<br>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<input type="hidden" name="id_yate" value="' . $row["id_yate"] . '">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<input type="hidden" name="id_capitan" value="' . $row["id_capitan"] . '">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<input type="hidden" name="id_reserva" value="' . $row["id_reserva"] . '">';

        $contenidoHTML .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="accept" style="background-color: #000730; border-color: #000730;">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp;Accept';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</button>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="" style="background-color: #aab1b3; border-color: #848d8f;">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;Deny';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</a>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<a class="boton-detalles" href="details.html">';
        $contenidoHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Details';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</a>';
        $contenidoHTML .= '</div>'; // Cierre de cuadro
        $contenidoHTML .= '</form>';
    }

    return $contenidoHTML;
}

// Esta función se llama para cargar datos al cargar la página inicialmente
function cargarDatos() {
    $datosActualizados = obtenerDatosAsignaciones();
    echo $datosActualizados;
}

// Llama a la función para cargar datos al cargar la página inicialmente
cargarDatos();
?>
```

Así se vé : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la base de datos tengo estos registros :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto 91, como 92 deberían visualizarse porque el estado es "No Asignado", no tengo mas codigo adicional que genere algún tipo de restricción es todo lo que tengo no entiendo que puede estar pasando, agradezco mucho que me puedan ayudar

Comment: En tu consulta intervienen varias tablas, y puede que en alguna de esas tablas no haya coincidencias. Una forma rápida de depurarlo es cambiando temporalmente todos los `JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`, así verás `NULL` en los coincidentes y decidir qué hacer con esas no coincidencias, si normalizar los datos o repensar la lógica de tu código o de tu diseño de datos.

Comment: Perdón, quise decir *verás NULL en los **no** coincidentes*

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y funciona de maravilla, enserio espectacular. Ya se pueden ver los registros pero no veo null por ningún lado: https://i.imgur.com/rskVPWA.png

Comment: Ya, no ves `null` porque las no coincidencias no estarían en esos datos que estás mostrando, conviene que ejecutes la consulta directamente en la base de datos, así podrás ver los `null` y ver si tienes que normalizar algo, completar datos, dejar las cosas como están, etc. Eso no significa que no lo puedas dejar con `LEFT JOIN`, depende de la realidad de tus datos, de tu aplicación y de muchos factores que escapan al alcance de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que haya un problema serio en tu modelo de datos, y por eso no estás viendo los datos que esperas.

Tus consultas son del tipo `INNER JOIN`, que se pueden escribir como `JOIN` sin más. Ese tipo de unión sólo te traerá datos cuando haya coincidencias en las tablas que participan en la unión. Hay otros tipos de unión como `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN`, para entender este universo, puedes consultar por ejemplo la pregunta: *[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/29967)*

Si **temporalmente** tú cambias todos tus `INNER JOIN` (`JOIN` en tu código) por `LEFT JOIN`, vas a ver todos los datos que esperas. Pero, eso puede ser una *solución* o puede ser el revelador de un problema en tu diseño de datos.

Vamos a verlo en un fiddle, con esquemas sencillos de tus tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `capitanes` (
  `id_capitan` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `duenos` (
  `id_dueno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `yates` (
  `id_yate` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_dueno` INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_dueno`) REFERENCES `duenos` (`id_dueno`)
) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `reservas` (
  `id_reserva` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_yate` INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_yate`) REFERENCES `yates` (`id_yate`)
) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `asignacion_capitanes` (
  `id_asignacion` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_capitan` INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_capitan`) REFERENCES `capitanes` (`id_capitan`),
  `id_yate` INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_yate`) REFERENCES `yates` (`id_yate`)
) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

```
-- Data set

INSERT INTO `capitanes` VALUES 
  (1),
  (2);

INSERT INTO `duenos` VALUES 
  (1),
  (2);

INSERT INTO `yates` VALUES 
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (3,1);

INSERT INTO `reservas` VALUES 
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (3,1);

INSERT INTO `asignacion_capitanes` VALUES 
  (1,1,1),
  (2,2,2),
  (3,1,3);
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT 
  a.id_asignacion, 
  duenos.id_dueno, 
  y.id_yate,
  r.id_reserva, 
  a.id_capitan
FROM asignacion_capitanes a
  INNER JOIN capitanes c ON c.id_capitan = a.id_capitan 
  INNER JOIN yates y ON y.id_yate = a.id_yate 
  INNER JOIN duenos ON duenos.id_dueno = y.id_dueno 
  INNER JOIN reservas r ON r.id_yate = y.id_yate 
WHERE a.id_capitan = 1 
  ORDER BY a.id_asignacion DESC;
```

| id_asignacion | id_dueno | id_yate | id_reserva | id_capitan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

```
SELECT 
  a.id_asignacion, 
  duenos.id_dueno, 
  y.id_yate,
  r.id_reserva, 
  a.id_capitan
FROM asignacion_capitanes a
  LEFT JOIN capitanes c ON c.id_capitan = a.id_capitan 
  LEFT JOIN yates y ON y.id_yate = a.id_yate 
  LEFT JOIN duenos ON duenos.id_dueno = y.id_dueno 
  LEFT JOIN reservas r ON r.id_yate = y.id_yate 
WHERE a.id_capitan = 1 
  ORDER BY a.id_asignacion DESC;
```

| id_asignacion | id_dueno | id_yate | id_reserva | id_capitan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | *null* | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/12ZJDBFI)

En la primera consulta, con `INNER JOIN` tenemos **dos filas**, mientras que en la segunda tenemos **tres filas**. Bien, quizá esperas tres filas y te quedas contento con eso, pero, ¿no habría un problema con esos datos, o peor aún, con el diseño de esos datos? Lo que molesta en el segundo resultado es que hay un `id_reserva` con valor **`null`**.

Analicemos en los `INSERT` lo que ha pasado:

En la tabla **`reservas`** hay dos reservas para el yate `1` y una reserva para el yate `2`. Bien, eso no es problema, suponemos que un yate puede tener **más de una reserva**. ¿Dónde está entonces la inconsistencia? Pues que en **`asignacion_capitanes`** has asignado un capitán para el yate `3`, **pero ese yate no tiene reserva**.

Esto puede ser un problema grave de diseño. ¿Por qué el sistema permitió que se asigne un capitán a un yate que no tiene reserva?

Esto es sólo un ejemplo. La inconsistencia puede estar ocurriendo en otra parte. No vemos en la pregunta tus `CREATE TABLE`, conviene ponerlos siempre. Y puede que no tenga razón y que tu diseño esté bien. Pero es muy sospechoso. **Quizá las tablas `reservas` y `asignacion_capitanes`** hacen lo mismo. Es lo que parece, analizando el problema, aunque sin un profundo conocimiento de la finalidad de tu aplicación ni del diseño de tus tablas.