# ¿Cómo hago para que en las columnas no me de la misma información?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, prestashop, prestashop1.7

```
SELECT 

DISTINCT p.id_product,
       pl.name AS "Nombre",
       cl.name AS "Categoria",
       (ps.price + ps.ecotax) AS "Precio (con IVA)",
       IF(sa.quantity IS NULL OR sa.quantity = '', 0, sa.quantity) AS "Stock",
       m.name AS "Nombre de la marca",
       a.city AS "Ciudad"

FROM soft_product p, soft_manufacturer m, soft_address a, soft_category_lang cl, soft_profile_lang pl, soft_product_shop ps, soft_stock_available sa
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola miren tengo ese problema, me está dando los datos de la columna repetidos y yo no quiero eso, quiero que me los de solo 1 vez, ¿como lo puedo arreglar? Ahí arriba también les deje el código gracias

Comment: no estás utilizando joins, creo que por ahí va el asunto en primer lugar.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que el modelo relacional es un modelo que se basa en la teoría de conjuntos. Lo que ocurre es que estás haciendo un producto cartesiano de las tablas incluidas en tu cláusula `from`, ya que no indicas ningún *filtro*.

La respuesta correcta y corta a tu problema sería:

Tienes que indicar la manera de relacionar unas tablas con otras usando sentencias [`join`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36/21). Usualmente las tablas se relacionan por campos definidos en llaves foráneas. Un ejemplo, con un par de tablas de tu consulta, podría ser:

```
SELECT   p.id_product
       , m.name AS "Nombre de la marca"
  FROM soft_product p
       inner join soft_manufacturer m on m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer
```

Claro que, no es posible escribir la sentencia correcta sin conocer la estructura de las tablas y sus llaves y relaciones. Yo estoy *imaginando* los nombres de los campos y la posible relación entre las tablas.

La idea es que limites el resultado solo a los registros que tienen relación, por ejemplo, la sentencia que escribí solo devolverá los resultados que relacionan el registro de la tabla producto con la marca concreta de ese producto en la tabla de manufactureros.

Profundizando un poco, recuerda que un producto cartesiano es la combinación de todos los elementos de un conjunto con todos los elementos de otro conjunto, digamos que tengo los conjuntos

```
A = [a, b, c]
B = [1, 2, 3]
```

El producto cartesiano sería:

```
A x B = [(a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (b,1), (b,2), (b,3), (c,1), (c,2), (c,3)]
```

En SQL *moderno* (sintaxis definida en 1992) eso sería un *cross join*, pero en la sintaxis previa a 1992, que es la que estás utilizando, sería incluir las tablas en la cláusula from sin un *where* que defina sus relaciones.

Así, si cada una de tus tablas tuviese 10 registros, al incluir 7 tablas en la cláusula from, tendrías 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 = 10 000 000 de registros en el resultado.

Conceptualmente, de ese universo de registros, eliges solo los que son relevante mediante las condiciones escritas en cada cláusula `join`, y luego filtras los que te interesan con una cláusula `where`, si fuese necesario.

Answer (score 0):

No estás agregando un WHERE o los JOIN, básicamente te está trayendo todo lo que tienen tus tablas porque no hay algo que las filtre.

Debes agregarlos para tener el control de lo que te debe de mostrar.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]